# How do I find what is using memory in a Python process in a production system?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, coredump

My production system occasionally exhibits a memory leak I have not been able to reproduce in a development environment.  I've used a [Python memory profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/python-memory-profiler) (specifically, Heapy) with some success in the development environment, but it can't help me with things I can't reproduce, and I'm reluctant to instrument our production system with Heapy because it takes a while to do its thing and its threaded remote interface does not work well in our server.

What I think I want is a way to dump a snapshot of the production Python process (or at least gc.get_objects), and then analyze it offline to see where it is using memory.  [How do I get a core dump of a python process like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141802/how-do-i-dump-an-entire-python-process-for-later-debugging-inspection)  Once I have one, how do I do something useful with it?

Comment: What is your production platform, *nix or NT?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I will expand on Brett's answer from my recent experience. [Dozer package](https://pypi.org/project/Dozer/) is   [well maintained](https://github.com/mgedmin/dozer), and despite advancements, like addition of `tracemalloc` to stdlib in Python 3.4, its `gc.get_objects` counting chart is my go-to tool to tackle memory leaks. Below I use `dozer > 0.7` which has not been released at the time of writing (well, because I contributed a couple of fixes there recently).

## Example

Let's look at a non-trivial memory leak. I'll use [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) 4.4 here and will eventually uncover a feature which causes the leak (and because it's a bug/feature kind of thing, it can be called mere misconfiguration, cause by ignorance). So there's a Python 3.6 *venv* where I `pip install celery < 4.5`. And have the following module.

*demo.py*

```
import time

import celery 


redis_dsn = 'redis://localhost'
app = celery.Celery('demo', broker=redis_dsn, backend=redis_dsn)

@app.task
def subtask():
    pass

@app.task
def task():
    for i in range(10_000):
        subtask.delay()
        time.sleep(0.01)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    task.delay().get()
```

Basically a task which schedules a bunch of subtasks. What can go wrong?

I'll use [`procpath`](https://pypi.org/project/Procpath/) to analyse Celery node memory consumption. `pip install procpath`. I have 4 terminals:

1. `procpath record -d celery.sqlite -i1 "$..children[?('celery' in @.cmdline)]"` to record the Celery node's process tree stats
2. `docker run --rm -it -p 6379:6379 redis` to run Redis which will serve as Celery broker and result backend
3. `celery -A demo worker --concurrency 2` to run the node with 2 workers
4. `python demo.py` to finally run the example

(4) will finish under 2 minutes.

Then I use [sqliteviz](https://github.com/lana-k/sqliteviz) ([pre-built version](https://lana-k.github.io/sqliteviz/)) to visualise what `procpath` has recorder. I drop the `celery.sqlite` there and use this query:

```
SELECT datetime(ts, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') ts, stat_pid, stat_rss / 256.0 rss
FROM record
```

And in sqliteviz I create a line chart trace with `X=ts`, `Y=rss`, and add split transform `By=stat_pid`. The result chart is:

[image: Celery node leak]

This shape is likely pretty familiar to anyone who fought with memory leaks.

## Finding leaking objects

Now it's time for `dozer`. I'll show non-instrumented case (and you can instrument your code in similar way if you can). To inject Dozer server into target process I'll use [Pyrasite](https://pypi.org/project/pyrasite/) (update: try a fork, [Pyrasite-ng](https://pypi.org/project/pyrasite-ng/), if Pyrasite doesn't work). There are two things to know about it:

- To run it, [ptrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) has to be configured as "classic ptrace permissions": `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`, which is may be a security risk
- There are non-zero chances that your target Python process will crash

With that caveat I:

- `pip install https://github.com/mgedmin/dozer/archive/3ca74bd8.zip` (that's to-be 0.8 I mentioned above)
- `pip install pillow` (which `dozer` uses for charting)
- `pip install pyrasite`

After that I can get Python shell in the target process:

```
pyrasite-shell 26572
```

And inject the following, which will run Dozer's WSGI application using stdlib's `wsgiref`'s server.

```
import threading
import wsgiref.simple_server

import dozer


def run_dozer():
    app = dozer.Dozer(app=None, path='/')
    with wsgiref.simple_server.make_server('', 8000, app) as httpd:
        print('Serving Dozer on port 8000...')
        httpd.serve_forever()

threading.Thread(target=run_dozer, daemon=True).start()
```

Opening `http://localhost:8000` in a browser there should see something like:

[image: dozer]

After that I run `python demo.py` from (4) again and wait for it to finish. Then in Dozer I set "Floor" to 5000, and here's what I see:

[image: dozer shows Celery leak]

Two types related to Celery grow as the subtask are scheduled:

- `celery.result.AsyncResult`
- `vine.promises.promise`

`weakref.WeakMethod` has the same shape and numbers and must be caused by the same thing.

## Finding root cause

At this point from the leaking types and the trends it may be already clear what's going on in your case. If it's not, Dozer has "TRACE" link per type, which allows tracing (e.g. seeing object's attributes) chosen object's referrers (`gc.get_referrers`) and referents (`gc.get_referents`), and continue the process again traversing the graph.

But a picture says a thousand words, right? So I'll show how to use [`objgraph`](https://pypi.org/project/objgraph/) to render chosen object's dependency graph.

- `pip install objgraph`
- `apt-get install graphviz`

Then:

- I run `python demo.py` from (4) again
- in Dozer I set `floor=0`, `filter=AsyncResult`
- and click "TRACE" which should yield

[image: trace]

Then in Pyrasite shell run:

```
objgraph.show_backrefs([objgraph.at(140254427663376)], filename='backref.png')
```

The PNG file should contain:

[image: backref chart]

Basically there's some `Context` object containing a `list` called `_children` that in turn is containing many instances of `celery.result.AsyncResult`, which leak. Changing `Filter=celery.*context` in Dozer here's what I see:

[image: Celery context]

So the culprit is `celery.app.task.Context`. Searching that type would certainly lead you to [Celery task page](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html). Quickly searching for "children" there, here's what it says:

> `trail = True`
>
> If enabled the request will keep track of subtasks started by this task, and this information will be sent with the result (`result.children`).

Disabling the trail by setting `trail=False` like:

```
@app.task(trail=False)
def task():
    for i in range(10_000):
        subtask.delay()
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

Then restarting the Celery node from (3) and `python demo.py` from (4) yet again, shows this memory consumption.

[image: solved]

Problem solved!

Comment: That is awesome debugging @saaj ! From your minimal example it looks to be a bug/leak in the trail functionality of celery 4.4 , do you know if this was ever reported to celery?

Comment: @tutuDajuju Thanks. Regarding reporting the behaviour/bug/leak, given the diversity of cases Celery is used in, I wasn't sure it would be perceived as a bug. The trail feature is described as to *keep track of subtasks started by this task*, which means some objects has to be kept for the duration of the task. The latter can be a bug/leak or work as intended, depending on the perspective. So I didn't report it, and did find an existing report when I faced with the behaviour myself.

Answer (score 41):

Using Python's `gc` garbage collector interface and `sys.getsizeof()` it's possible to dump all the python objects and their sizes. Here's the code I'm using in production to troubleshoot a memory leak:

```
rss = psutil.Process(os.getpid()).get_memory_info().rss
# Dump variables if using more than 100MB of memory
if rss > 100 * 1024 * 1024:
    memory_dump()
    os.abort()

def memory_dump():
    dump = open("memory.pickle", 'wb')
    xs = []
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        i = id(obj)
        size = sys.getsizeof(obj, 0)
        #    referrers = [id(o) for o in gc.get_referrers(obj) if hasattr(o, '__class__')]
        referents = [id(o) for o in gc.get_referents(obj) if hasattr(o, '__class__')]
        if hasattr(obj, '__class__'):
            cls = str(obj.__class__)
            xs.append({'id': i, 'class': cls, 'size': size, 'referents': referents})
    cPickle.dump(xs, dump)
```

Note that I'm only saving data from objects that have a `__class__` attribute because those are the only objects I care about. It should be possible to save the complete list of objects, but you will need to take care choosing other attributes. Also, I found that getting the referrers for each object was extremely slow so I opted to save only the referents. Anyway, after the crash, the resulting pickled data can be read back like this:

```
with open("memory.pickle", 'rb') as dump:
    objs = cPickle.load(dump)
```

### Added 2017-11-15

The Python 3.6 version is here:

```
import gc
import sys
import _pickle as cPickle

def memory_dump():
    with open("memory.pickle", 'wb') as dump:
        xs = []
        for obj in gc.get_objects():
            i = id(obj)
            size = sys.getsizeof(obj, 0)
            #    referrers = [id(o) for o in gc.get_referrers(obj) if hasattr(o, '__class__')]
            referents = [id(o) for o in gc.get_referents(obj) if hasattr(o, '__class__')]
            if hasattr(obj, '__class__'):
                cls = str(obj.__class__)
                xs.append({'id': i, 'class': cls, 'size': size, 'referents': referents})
        cPickle.dump(xs, dump)
```

Comment: Looks like sys.getsizeof has some important limitations to keep in mind: http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof  Namely, new in 2.6 and "default will be returned if the object does not provide means to retrieve the size. Otherwise a TypeError will be raised."

Comment: @keturn Using pickle.dump() multiple times to the same file means we can save a lot of memory by not storing the entire list of objects in memory before pickling them. This is helpful in my program because it is already running out memory when I start the dump

Comment: Great answer. An update, instead of psutil.Process(os.getpid()).get_memory_info().rss it should be psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss on Python 2.7

Comment: You should add 'import psutil'

Answer (score 5):

Could you record the traffic (via a log) on your production site, then re-play it on your development server instrumented with a python memory debugger? (I recommend dozer: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Dozer)

Comment: Might be worth a shot.  There are various considerations, like how much disk write i/o I would use up and lining up the right database snapshot to work with the recorded inputs, but if we could get it working, it would be an incredibly useful tool.

Answer (score 4):

[Make your program dump core](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=gcore), then clone an instance of the program on a sufficiently similar box using [gdb](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=gdb).  There are [special macros](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb) to help with debugging python programs within gdb, but if you can get your program to concurrently [serve up a remote shell](http://blog.vrplumber.com/index.php?/archives/1631-Minimal-example-of-using-twisted.manhole-Since-it-took-me-so-long-to-get-it-working....html), you could just continue the program's execution, and query it with python.

I have never had to do this, so I'm not 100% sure it'll work, but perhaps the pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Installing a Manhole would be incredibly helpful, yes.  Sadly, this is not a Twisted application.

Comment: See [here](http://blog.futurefoundries.com/2013/04/ssh-into-your-python-server.html) how you can use a Manhole in (e.g.) a Flask application.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to dump an entire python interpreter state and restore it. It would be useful, I'll keep my eye on this answer in case anyone else has ideas.

If you have an idea where the memory is leaking, you can add checks the refcounts of your objects. For example:

```
x = SomeObject()
... later ...
oldRefCount = sys.getrefcount( x )
suspiciousFunction( x )
if (oldRefCount != sys.getrefcount(x)):
    print "Possible memory leak..."
```

You could also check for reference counts higher than some number that is reasonable for your app. To take it further, you could modify the python interpreter to do these kinds of check by replacing the `Py_INCREF` and `Py_DECREF` macros with your own. This might be a bit dangerous in a production app, though.

Here is an essay with more info on debugging these sorts of things. It's more geared for plugin authors but most of it applies.

[Debugging Reference Counts](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/refcnt/)

Comment: Unfortunately that "idea of where memory is leaking" is what I am trying to get.  That look-for-high-reference-counts approach might be useful though.

Answer (score 2):

The [`gc` module](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-gc.html) has some functions that might be useful, like listing all objects the garbage collector found to be unreachable but cannot free, or a list of all objects being tracked.

If you have a suspicion which objects might leak, the [weakref](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-weakref.html) module could be handy to find out if/when objects are collected.

Comment: Yeah.  If I could just figure out how to grab something like gc.get_objects and export it to be analyzed later.  I don't think I can use pickle for that, as not everything is pickleable.

Answer (score 2):

[Meliae](https://edge.launchpad.net/meliae) looks promising:

> This project is similar to heapy (in the 'guppy' project), in its attempt to understand how memory has been allocated.
>
> Currently, its main difference is that it splits the task of computing summary statistics, etc of memory consumption from the actual scanning of memory consumption. It does this, because I often want to figure out what is going on in my process, while my process is consuming huge amounts of memory (1GB, etc). It also allows dramatically simplifying the scanner, as I don't allocate python objects while trying to analyze python object memory consumption.