# django tests - error in github action while running in parallel

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing, github-actions, django-testing

in a github action yml file it's defined this step to run django tests:

```
python manage.py test --failfast --parallel 2
```

looks like `--parallel 2` breaks it:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 449, in _run_subsuite
    result = runner.run(subsuite)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 366, in run
    test(result)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/unittest/suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/unittest/suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 381, in __call__
    self._setup_and_call(result)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 416, in _setup_and_call
    super().__call__(result)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/unittest/case.py", line 650, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/unittest/case.py", line 599, in run
    self._feedErrorsToResult(result, outcome.errors)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/unittest/case.py", line 516, in _feedErrorsToResult
    result.addFailure(test, exc_info)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 296, in addFailure
    self.check_picklable(test, err)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 216, in check_picklable
    self._confirm_picklable(err)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 186, in _confirm_picklable
    pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(obj))
TypeError: cannot pickle 'traceback' object
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/fiscozen/fiscozen/fiscozen_django/manage.py", line 24, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 24, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 68, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 1061, in run_tests
    result = self.run_suite(suite)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 983, in run_suite
    return runner.run(suite)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/unittest/runner.py", line 184, in run
    test(result)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/unittest/suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 534, in run
    subsuite_index, events = test_results.next(timeout=0.1)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 873, in next
    raise value
TypeError: cannot pickle 'traceback' object
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

anybody experienced it?

Comment: this looks familiar, I believe I had to `pip install tblib` to get the actual traceback but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I pickle an error's Traceback in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132469/why-cant-i-pickle-an-errors-traceback-in-python)

Comment: @Azeem yes it does