# Dowser: "bad argument to internal function"

Tags: python, memory-management

I'm trying out [Dowser](http://www.aminus.net/wiki/Dowser), it's really cool but I'm stuck with a little problem, and I couldn't find anything helpful on Google, so here I am.. ^^;

I'm running a CherryPy+SQLAlchemy application.. It works normally, except that when I enable Dowser (that is, after I call dowser.Root()), now and then I get exceptions like:

> SystemError:
>   ../Objects/tupleobject.c:809: bad
>   argument to internal function

on innocent-looking istructions, such as accessing a SQLA-mapped field.. Relevant part of a traceback:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.5.8-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 158, in __get__
    return self.impl.get(instance_state(instance), instance_dict(instance))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.5.8-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 377, in get
    value = callable_()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.5.8-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py", line 586, in __call__
    result = q.all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.5.8-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1267, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.5.8-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1422, in instances
    rows = [process[0](context, row) for row in fetch]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.5.8-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2032, in main
    return _instance(row, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.5.8-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1653, in _instance
    identitykey = identity_key(row)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.5.8-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1594, in identity_key
    return (identity_class, tuple(row[column] for column in pk_cols))
```

Could this be related to the Dowser thread, accessing the garbage collector? Any hint on what I could check out?

I'm running Python 2.6.2 on Xubuntu Jaunty.

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: 13 years later... and it's still there! An application on Python 3.8.10, SQLAlchemy 1.4.25, and Dozer 0.8 running for a few hours crashes with the same `SystemError: ../Objects/tupleobject.c:892: bad argument to internal function`.

Answer (score 1):

## Abstract

In my case it's [Dozer](https://pypi.org/project/Dozer/), not Dowser, but it's basically the same thing --
looping over `gc.get_objects` and counting types in a separate thread. And optionally tracing referrers and referents of the chosen objects
interactively.

As I mentioned in the comment this error still takes place. On SQLAlchemy I
had two stack traces of `SystemError: ../Objects/tupleobject.c:892: bad  argument to internal function` exception raised in tuple comprehensions ([one](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/rel_1_4_25/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L2361-L2386), [two](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/rel_1_4_25/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/annotation.py#L31-L42)). Here's a plausible explanation.

## Explanation

If I look at CPython source of `tupleobject.c` [line 892](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.10/Objects/tupleobject.c#L892), there's a
notable comment preceding the function:

> The following function breaks the notion that tuples are immutable:
> it changes the size of a tuple.  We get away with this only if there
> is only one module referencing the object.  You can also think of it
> as creating a new tuple object and destroying the old one, only more
> efficiently.  In any case, don't use this if the tuple may already be
> known to some other part of the code.

Proposition:

- while SQLAlchemy is building its complex tuple comprehension in the main
  thread,
- Dozer grabs a reference to the "work-in-progress" tuple, from another
  thread,
- and breaks the assumption of `_PyTuple_Resize` (that there's only 1
  referrer for non-empty tuple)

```c
    if (v == NULL || Py_TYPE(v) != &PyTuple_Type ||
        (Py_SIZE(v) != 0 && Py_REFCNT(v) != 1)) {
        *pv = 0;
        Py_XDECREF(v);
        PyErr_BadInternalCall();  // line 892
        return -1;
    }
```

## Takeaway

Dozer is a great live memory inspection tool, but it's limited in the way that
the application under inspection instrumented with Dozer may not survive a
long run (e.g. survives a few hours). Hence, it's more practical to wait until the memory leak manifests
and only then [live attach Dozer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61260839/2072035) to the process.