# python memory reclaim about dict and list

Tags: python, memory

Recently, I've got confused about memory management of python. First is about dict, say I have
a composite dict object like

```
d = {id1: {'x': 'a', 'y': [1,2,3], 'z': {'k', 'v'}}, id2: {...}}
```

if I call del,

```
del d[id1]
```

Will the d[id1]['y'] and d[id1]['z'] be reclaimed together?

Second is about list, I read the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641231/python-working-around-memory-leaks/1641280#1641280), so I tried it. Here is my code

```
import sys
import gc
import time
from collections import defaultdict 
from pprint import pprint 

def f():
    d = defaultdict(int) 
    objects = gc.get_objects() 
    for o in objects: 
        d[type(o)] += 1
    x = d.items()
    x = sorted(x, key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)
    pprint(x[:5]) 

def loop():
    while True:
        leaked = [[x] for x in range(100)]
        f()
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

when the range is 100, well, the function f indeed showed me the list was increasing, but when
I modify the range to 1000, there is nothing to change, the amount of list keep the same.
Anybody could tell me what's the problem?

Answer (score 5):

`del` removes that reference to the object in the current namespace.  *In Cpython*, when an object's reference count reaches 0, it will be available for python to use for future objects (It doesn't necessarily go back to the OS).

consider:

```
a = []
b = a
del a #The list doesn't get freed because `b` is still a reference to that list
```

In your scenario, when you `del d[id1]`, you remove a reference to that (inner) dictionary.  Since it is holding a bunch of references to other objects, each of those objects now have 1 less reference.  If their reference count reaches 0, they'll be collected and every object they hold a reference to will have its refcount decremented and so on.

Answer (score 1):

**"Will the d[id1]['y'] and d[id1]['z'] be reclaimed together?"**

Assuming nothing else references that dictionary or the contents of it, then it all goes to a ref count 0 at the same time. however, there's no guarantee that any of that wil lbe immediately collected.

**"....Anybody could tell me what's the problem?"**

Python caches the low integer objects, so they will always be referenced:

http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html - "The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object."

That may explain the behaviour you're seeing. Instead of using x in range(100), create anonymous objects, e.g.

```
leaked = [object() for x in range(100)]
```

Comment: yes, when I use anonymous object, there is no growth on <type list>, but the <type tuple> keeps going, seems odd