# Fastest way of getting OpenGraph metatags from HTML?

Tags: python, html, parsing, facebook-opengraph, lxml

Beautiful Soup is not efficient enough, so I'm trying to use pure `lxml`. However, the `lxml.html.fromstring` is buggy ([it suddenly eats 100% RAM after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260261/lxml-parser-eats-all-memory)), so I need to do it some other way (not with `fromstring`).

Could I use any of the other modules in the API?  I can't figure it out, and there are surprisingly close to nil examples out there on the internets.

This is what I'm doing now, but as I said, I need to replace the `fromstring`:

```
        mySearchTree = fromstring(data)
        metas = {}
        n = -1
        for a in mySearchTree.cssselect('meta'):
            n += 1
            metas[n] = {}
            for b in a.items():
                metas[n][b[0]] = b[1]
        y = 0
        tag = []
        for m in metas:
            if 'property' in metas[m] and 'content' in metas[m]:
                if 'og:' in metas[m]['property']:
                    y += 1
                    tag.append({metas[m]['property'] : metas[m]['content']})

        for x in tag:
            for y in x:
                #print '%s ==> %s' % (y, x[y])
                self.rj[y] = x[y]
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at `etree.iterparse`. If used correctly, it works well. I parsed a 10GB XML file in like 20mb of RAM.

Comment: Does it work with HTML as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As OpenGraph tags are usually at the beginning of HTML document, you could read and parse only part of the input file. Probability the `HEAD` part will be huge is very small I think (although your research can lead to a different opinion, depends on your sample).

1. Setup chunk size (e.g. 1024 bytes).
2. Read input file chunk by chunk (something like `stream.read(1024)`) until there is `</head>` (or `</HEAD>`, or `<body>`, etc.) present in the buffer. Decide on limit - number of bytes to read at maximum in case the input is corrupted and has no header or so, so you can give up soon enough you consume a lot of memory.
3. Use `lxml.html` parser to read the fragment you have buffered (it's not valid, but it does not matter, `lxml` can deal with it and it won't affect our goal).
4. Now, you have `lxml` DOM object with head of the HTML file. It was created efficiently and with no risk of excessive memory consumption. You can do any searches, extractions, etc. I'd use `xpath`, but feel free to use your funky DOM tickling code you have above in your question.