# python threading as a way to complete a script that allways crashes

Tags: python, multithreading, lxml

I've been struggling for many days now with a class PublicationSaver() that I wrote that has a method for loading xml documents as strings (not shown here) and then it passes each loaded string to self.savePublication(self, publication, myDirPath).

Every time I have used it crashed after about 25.000 strings and it saves the last string on which it crashes, I was able parse that string separately so I suppose that the problem is not bad XML.

I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030660/python-lxml-crashing-after-parsing-thousand-documents-fromstring) but no answers.

I goggled a lot and it seems that I'm not the only one having this problem: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260261/lxml-parser-eats-all-memory)

So, since I really need to complete this task, I thought this: can I wrap all with a Thread set in main, so that when lxml parse throws an exception I get it and send a result to main to kill the thread and start it again?

```html
#threading
result_q = Queue.Queue()

# Create the thread 
xmlSplitter = XmlSplitter_Thread(result_q=result_q)
xmlSplitter.run(toSplit_DirPath, target_DirPath)

print "Hello !!!\n"

toSplitDirEmptyB=False

while not toSplitDirEmptyB:
  
    splitterAlive=True
    while splitterAlive:
        sleep(120)
        splitterAlive=result_q.get()
        
    xmlSplitter.join()
    print "*** KILLED XmlSplitter_Thread !!! ***\n"
    
    if not os.listdir(toSplit_DirPath):
        toSplitDirEmptyB=True
    else:
        xmlSplitter.run(toSplit_DirPath, target_DirPath)
```

Is this a valid approach ? When I run the code above at the moment is not working; I mean I never get the "Hello !!" displayed and the xmlSplitter just keep going even when it starts to fail (there's an exception rule that keeps it going).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the thread fails and its blocking on join method. take a look [here](https://gist.github.com/benallard/8042835) . Split the xml into chunks and try to parse the chunk to avoid memory errors.