# Memory management when downloading data in a function that's repeatedly called

Tags: python, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have just seen my Python process get killed again on my VPS with 1GB of RAM and am now looking into optimizing memory usage in my program.

I've got a function that downloads a web page, looks for data and then returns a Pandas Dataframe with what it found. This function is called thousands of times from within a for loop that ends up maxing out the memory on my server.

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
93     75.6 MiB      1.2 MiB           1           page = http.get(url)                
94     75.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           if page.status_code == 200:                        
95     78.4 MiB      2.8 MiB           1               tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
96     78.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               del page 

... code to search for data using xpaths and assign to data dict

117     78.4 MiB      0.1 MiB           1               df = pd.DataFrame(data)                        
118     78.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               del tree
119     78.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               gc.collect()
120     78.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               return df
```

With the memory_profiler results from above, it shows that the lines of my code with the largest memory increments are as expected: the `http.get()` and `html.fromstring()` calls and assignments. The actual Dataframe creation is much smaller in comparison.

Now I would expect that the only overall memory increase to my program is the size of the dataframe returned by the function and not ALSO the size of both the `page` and `tree` objects. With every call to this function, the memory increase on my program is the combination of all 3 objects and this does not ever decrease.

I have tried adding `del` before the end of the function to attempt to de-reference the objects I don't need anymore, but this does not seem to make a difference.

I do see that for a scalable application I would need to start saving to disk, but at this point even if I do save to disk I'm not sure how to free up the memory already used.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging, I finally found the answer to my own question. The issue was related to string results from my xpath expressions that by default use "smart-strings" that are known to eat up memory. Disabling these gives me the kind of memory consumption I was expecting.

More information [lxml parser eats all memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260261/lxml-parser-eats-all-memory) and https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath-return-values