# Apparent memory leak with numpy tolist() in long running process

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I run a server which acts as a data processing node for clients within the team.  Recently we've been refactoring legacy code within the server to leverage **numpy** for some of the filtering/transform jobs.

As we have to serve this data out to remote clients, we convert the numpy data to various forms, using **numpy.tolist()** as an intermediary step.

Each query is stateless, there are no globals, and so between queries no references are be maintained.

In one particular step I get an apparent memory leak, which I have been trying to trackdown via **memory_profiler**.    This step involves converting a large (>4m entries) ndarray of floats to a python list.  The first time I issue the query the tolist() call allocates 120m of memory, and then deallocates 31m when I release the numpy array.  The second (and subsequent times) I issue the identical query the allocation/deallocation is 31m.  Each different query I issue has the same pattern, though with different absolute values.

I've torn apart my code, and forced in some del commands for illustrative purposes.  Output, below, is from **memory_profiler.profile**

First issue of query:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
   865    296.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           p = ikeyData[1]['value']
   866    417.2 MiB    120.6 MiB           newArr = p.tolist()
   867    417.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           del p
   868    385.6 MiB    -31.6 MiB           del ikeyData[1]['value']
   869    385.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           ikeyData[1]['value'] = newArr
```

Second(and subsequent) instances of same query:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
   865    494.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           p = ikeyData[1]['value']
   866    526.3 MiB     31.6 MiB           newArr = p.tolist()
   867    526.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           del p
   868    494.7 MiB    -31.6 MiB           del ikeyData[1]['value']
   869    494.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           ikeyData[1]['value'] = newArr
```

As you can imagine, in a long-running process with highly variable queries, these allocations build up forcing us to regularly bounce the server.

Does anyone have thoughts as to what might be happening here?

Comment: The first thought is to examine numpy's source.

Comment: If only the first run produces excessive allocation - how do they "build up"?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435415/python-memory-leaks

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev each unique query produces a different excessive initial allocation.  We have thousands of unique queries on a given day.

Comment: As the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435415/python-memory-leaks) and [Mike's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34022660/648265) say, you should be inspecting Python's GC rather than raw memory footprint. The latter could only be useful if the former shows nothing - then an excessive memory fragmentation is happening, and the memory management facilities are at fault, or `numpy` is leaking (both are extremely unlikely). There's really nothing else we can say without a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

In your case Python has probably released the memory.

This does not mean that the memory allocator necessarily returns the memory
to the operating system. `memory_profiler` uses system calls to find out the current amount of used memory. So probably nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: If they "have to bounce the server regularly", there probably _is_ something wrong - whether with their code or some other.

Comment: The logging suggest a one-time  use of 89 MiB that is not released. No sign of built-up there. Looks like the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @MikeMüller Each unique query produces a one-time allocation at that line of code.  I'm the first to admit the problem could be elsewhere, but this is the only place I can find strange behaviour like this that correlates to the growth of memory over time.

Comment: Every query is entirely separate, and yes there are threads behind it.

I had considered whether the threading architecture was holding onto the allocation.  However, later in this code **ikeyData[1]['value']** is discarded as I render out to JSON.

This occurs at a layer where the threading architecture has no access to the list in question, or the mechanics of the ikeyData dict.

From the perspective of the threading architecture, it calls a function which returns a string.