# Memory leakage while using python 2.7

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, memory-leaks

I am running gem5 simulator which uses C++ and python, and I have added more codes to it. When I use python 2.6 everything is alright, but the same code on a system with python 2.7 has very high memory leakage. The code is so big and I have no idea where is the source for memory leakage. I checked the code several times and it seems every object has been deleted.

Is it related to python version? How can I find the source of memory leakage?

Comment: Did it leak on 2.7 before you "added more codes to it"?  I suggest you get to a point where there is no leak, then makes changes one step at a time, monitoring for leaks after each change.

Comment: No memory leak before I add my code. However, my code only includes C++ code and no python code. Incremental coding is not possible, since the code is huge.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this memory leakage *is* related to python and *not* e.g. C++, you should check out [this thread on tracking down such leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435415/python-memory-leaks). [The LShift Blog describes](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2008/11/14/tracing-python-memory-leaks/) scenarios, in which Python can leak memory:

1. a C-library used leaks memory
2. the Python code you write/use has global lists or dicts that grow over time and you forgot to remove objects after usage
3. there are some [reference cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting#Dealing_with_reference_cycles) in the code