# Memory keep accumulating while training by PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am training a deep learning model using PyTorch. Due to unknown reasons, memory keeps accumulating, which leads to session killed under 30 epochs and underfitting.

Some thoughts here:

1. Wondering if it's caused by `matplotlib` so I added `plt.close('all')`; didn't work
2. Added `gc.collect()`; didn't work
3. Wondering if it's caused by `cv2.imwrite()`, but don't know how to inspect this. Any suggestions?
4. PyTorch issues?
5. others...

   ```
   model.train()
   for epo in range(epoch):
       for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
           inputs = data
           inputs = Variable(inputs)
           optimizer.zero_grad()

           top = model.upward(inputs + white(inputs))
           outputs = model.downward(top, shortcut = True)


           loss = criterion(inputs, outputs)
           loss.backward()
           optimizer.step()

           # Print generated pictures every 100 iters
           if i % 100 == 0:
               inn = inputs[0].view(128, 128).detach().numpy() * 255
               cv2.imwrite("/home/tk/Documents/recover/" + str(epo) + "_" + str(i) + ".png", inn)

               out = outputs[0].view(128, 128).detach().numpy() * 255
               cv2.imwrite("/home/tk/Documents/recover/" + str(epo) + "_" + str(i) + "_re.png", out)

           # Print loss every 50 iters
           if i % 50 == 0:
               print ('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' % (epo, i, loss.item()))

       gc.collect()
       plt.close("all")
   ```

===================================================================

## 20181222 Update

#### Datasets & DalaLoader

```
class MSourceDataSet(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, clean_dir):



        for i in cleanfolder:
            with open(clean_dir + '{}'.format(i)) as f:
                clean_list.append(torch.Tensor(json.load(f)))


        cleanblock = torch.cat(clean_list, 0)
        self.spec = cleanblock


    def __len__(self):
        return self.spec.shape[0]


    def __getitem__(self, index): 

        spec = self.spec[index]
        return spec

trainset = MSourceDataSet(clean_dir)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = trainset,
                                            batch_size = 4,
                                            shuffle = True)
```

The model is really complicated and long...plus the memory accumulation issue didn't happen before (using the same model), so I will not post it here...

Comment: Something hidden in trainloader, maybe?

Comment: Could you please post your model code? Do you maybe store batch-information in the model?

Comment: @cleros The model is really complicated and long...plus the memory accumulation issue didn't happen before (using the same model), so I will not post it here...
But could you possibly give some examples about batch-information storing you mentioned? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why don't you try tracking memory leaks to avoid guessing (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435415/python-memory-leaks))