# How to find a real cause for Python segmentation fault

Tags: python, dataframe, segmentation-fault

Python script generates segmentation fault
I cannot find the source of the problem.
How is it to debug a segfault simply in Python ?
Are there recommended coding practices to avoid Segmentation Faults ?

I wrote a script (1600 lines) to systematically download CSV files from a source and format the collected data. The script works very well for 100-200 files, but it systematically crashes with a segmentation fault message after a while.
-Crash always happens at the same spot in the script, with no understandable cause
-I run it on Mac OSX but the crash also happens on Ubuntu Linux and Debian 9
-If I run the Pandas Routines that crash during my script on single files, they work properly. The crash only happens when I loop the script 100-200 times.
-I checked every variable content, constructors (**init**) and they seem to be fine.

Code is too long to be pasted, but available on demand

Expected result should be execution to the end. Instead, it crashes after 100-200 iterations

Comment: A segmentation fault in a Python script is a bug in Python or one of the libraries. It's not usually something in your program that you can debug.

Comment: It’s possible to run `python` under a debugger and convert the segfault into a Python exception—just to get a traceback to narrow the candidates.  It’s unwise to try to continue from such a state, and the buggy C code (as Barmar said) may have run in a separate call *before* the arrival of the signal.

Comment: Relevant [python-memory-leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435415/python-memory-leaks)