# View memory distribution of a complex object

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks

I'm trying to debug a memory leak in my program. I have tracked the high memory usage to a certain, seemingly innocuous class instance. Unfortunately, it's a very complex object with lots of attributes pointing to other class instances that again have lots of attributes.

How do I visualize the memory distribution of this structure? I would like to know exactly *which* attribute, or which structures of the object, is consuming all the memory.

Comment: What did you think of the links in the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435415/python-memory-leaks