# monkey patch memory leaks external packages python

Tags: python, memory-leaks, pip, package, monkeypatching

I'm trying to understand if there is a way to avoid memory leaks in python in general. It happened a few times already that I had to use external pip packages that gave me memory leaks issues.

I would like to know a way to always monkey patch this.

More specifically, does wrapping the guilty code in a python process always help? if not, why? Is there some other way deal with this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435415/python-memory-leaks)

Comment: I'm afraid this question is too broad and you won't get any good answers here, not sure where you'd find more help on this, but this question is very similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435415/python-memory-leaks