# Why is my memory usage steadily increasing despite my variables not changing significantly in size?

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

When I run the code below on a large corpus of many gigabytes of parquet files, the memory usage steadily increases, e.g. from 3% per core at 10 minutes to 7% at 30 minutes to 10%+ at 6 hours. This despite my explicit call to `gc.collect()` and the fact that the files are all approximately the same size, and that only one file should be loaded at a time. I don't see any persistent references to old files, so I am stumped.

This problem forces me to limit the number of cores I use to tokenize my data, doubling my processing time.

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
import pandas as pd
import re
import string
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
import gc
import glob


def adjust_tokens(tokens):
    new_tokens = []
    number_regex = '[0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?'
    for token in tokens:
        if token in string.punctuation:
            continue
        if token == '...':
            continue
        if re.match(number_regex, token):
            new_tokens.append('aquantity')
        else:
            new_tokens.append(token.lower())
    return new_tokens


class ParquetsIterable():
    def __init__(self, tokenizer=None, indir=None, infiles=None,
                 filters=None, keys=None):
        if tokenizer is not None:
            self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        else:
            self.tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(
                r'(?:\w+)(?:[.-]\w+)*[-+]?|(?:[.][.][.])'
                + r'|(?:[!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~])'
                                            )
        if infiles is not None:
            self.infiles = infiles
        else:
            self.infiles = [os.path.join(indir, f) for f in os.listdir(indir)]
        self.filters = filters
        self.keys = keys

    def __iter__(self):
        for filename in self.infiles:
            try:
                df = pd.read_parquet(filename)
            except Exception:
                print('Invalid parquet file %s\n' % filename)
                continue
            if self.keys is not None:
                try:
                    assert (self.keys[filename].values
                            == df['key'].values).all()
                except AssertionError:
                    # This never happens
                    print('Skipping %s because of reorderinging'
                          ' and my unwillingness to write in a join'
                          % filename)
                    continue
            if self.filters is not None:
                df = df[self.filters[filename].values]
            gc.collect()
            for text in df['sentences']:
                for sentence in text.split('\n'):
                    yield adjust_tokens(self.tokenizer.tokenize(sentence))


def write_iterables_to_files(iterables, files, n_cores=8):
    pairs = zip(iterables, files)
    with Pool(n_cores) as p:
        p.map(write_iterable_to_file, pairs)


def write_iterable_to_file(iterable_and_file):
    iterable, file_ = iterable_and_file
    with open(file_, 'w') as f:
        for tokens in iterable:
            f.write(' '.join(tokens) + '\n')


if '__name__' == '__main__':
    files = sorted([f for f in glob.glob('data/sentence-parquets/*')
                    if 'parts' in f and 'sampled' not in f])
    os.makedirs('data/processed-sentences-text', exist_ok=True)
    iterables = [ParquetsIterable(infiles=files[i::8]) for i in range(8)]
    outfiles = ['data/processed-sentences-text/sentences-%d.txt' % i
                for i in range(8)]
    write_iterables_to_files(iterables, outfiles, n_cores=8)
```

Comment: The tokenization being wrapped up in an iterable is related to my intention to use the output of this with Gensim's Word2Vec model, although I no longer need this format (in fact, the purpose of write_iterable_to_files is to create something that can be iterated over more simply by a different class, since Gensim can't work in parallel when given the original ParquetsIterable class)..

Comment: I don't see anything immediately obvious that should lead to a memory leak. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435415/python-memory-leaks. But generally I'd say if you're waiting around ~8 hours for this to run you should definitely focus on optimizing your pandas operations using e.g. [vectorized string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html) rather than looping over all elements and manipulating each cell individually. you might see speedups of several orders of magnitude and significan memory use reductions making this issue moot.

Comment: It could be this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-14987