# How to debug memory leak on DigitalOcean App Platform

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean

My Django application run perfectly fine on my local machine, memory usage fluctuate between 700MB and 800MB, but when I execute the exact same code on DigitalOcean App Platform the memory usage is constantly increasing until it reach 100%. Then the application reboot.

What could cause the issue and how to find the root cause ?

I have tried to force the execution of the garbage collector with `gc.collect()` and also to isolate the problem with the `@profile` decorator from the `memory_profiler` package, but the memory incrementation isn't associated with any line of my code.

**Environnement version**

- Local : Python 3.10.12 + Ubuntu 22.04.3
- DigialOcean : Docker + Python 3.10.13

I track memory usage like this :

```
total = memory_usage()[0]
logger.info(f"Memory used : {total} MiB")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435415/python-memory-leaks)