# python module memory usage

Tags: python, memory

I have this python module that imports many other modules. On monitoring the vm usage of the module, I see the usage continuously growing. I tried to go through the whole code and assigned None to the objects\variables whereever possible. But I suspect there still could be something that is not freeing up the memory. Is there a way (through some 3rd party module or something) to view undisposed objects or their memory consumption?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Check out [How do I profile memory usage in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552744/how-do-i-profile-memory-usage-in-python) and [Which Python memory profiler is recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/python-memory-profiler). You need to dig into the docs, but those tools will allow you to breakdown memory usage by module.

Comment: thank you for your reply @Bialecki. I am going to try that. I looked over it quickly and looks like I will have to install that on my remote server.