# How to find Python Module Size

Tags: python

Googling didn't help in this case, I'm posting here. I was wondering if there is a way to find how much memory a module takes when imported into Python?

Thanks

Comment: Modules in Python are objects like everything else, so you might want to check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33978/find-out-how-much-memory-is-being-used-by-an-object-in-python

Comment: You could also try a Python memory profiler, such as [this one](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler).  Try running it on a program or function that imports the module you're looking for.

Comment: Already answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804493/python-module-memory-usage

Comment: This is also useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39096604/how-to-know-size-of-python-module