# How to know size of python module?

Tags: python

When I install the module using `pip install module_name`, I am able to see the size of either wheel or the package.

so the question is, is it possible to know just the size of each module?

something like this.

```
import pip

for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    print(distribution_size_only of dist)
```

I want to know estimated size of the distribution so that I can remove them from winpython distribution.

Comment: Define 'size'. `pip` shows how big the compressed archive is when you download it. Installation size will be vastly different from this, depending on wether or not there is a compiled extension there, or if there are easily compressable data files included, etc.

Comment: At any rate, the distribution size is not stored as metadata after installation, you'd have to query the original download location for the size of the archive for that version.

Comment: Also, what about dependencies; should those be included in the calculation? What is your end-goal here; calculate how much must be downloaded to reproduce the current setup?

Comment: Well if you want ``estimated``, then you can find it in my script below. Estimation not equals to 1:1 size right?

Comment: I Just want to know estimated size. I may be wrong but dependency are also comes under installed packages so their sizes will also be included.

Comment: Possibly related: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/winpython/diqzH4FNR_U

Comment: 100% related Thanks. But I am novice enough not  to understand how to make my own distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import pip


def calc_container(path):
    total_size = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)
    return total_size


for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    try:
        path = os.path.join(dist.location, dist.project_name)
        size = calc_container(path)
        if size:
            print path
            print size
    except OSError:
        '{} no longer exists'.format(dist.project_name)
```

If you're in virtualenv, you can use first option to get more:

> get_installed_distributions(local_only=True, skip=('python', 'wsgiref', 'argparse'), include_editables=True, editables_only=False, user_only=False)
>       Return a list of installed Distribution objects.
>
> If `local_only` is True (default), only return installations
>       local to the current virtualenv, if in a virtualenv.

Comment: This calculates *installed size* (but omits any installed scripts or datafiles). I *think* the OP wants to get the distribution size (`distribution_size_only` in the sample code).

Comment: @MartijnPieters who knows. Maybe yes, let's wait for Scripting.FileSystemObject note. Anyway it can be done, but won't take so fast, because if we are thinking about distributions, then we need to have also all dependencies that will be installed at once, if he would have global view of what would be installed. But as you know, we can copy and paste whole module to our project catalogue and import from it and it works. We don't have to install it, python module is a python module. It needs only to have all dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is vague but this is what I wanted:

```
import re
import requests
import json
def regexsubstring(s, p):
    p = re.compile(p, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return p.search(s)

def wf(data,path,mode):
    with open(path, mode, encoding='utf-8') as out:
        out.write(data)
        return

import pip
dists_size_info = {}

for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    url = "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/" + dist.key + "/" + dist.version
    r = requests.get(url)
    size = regexsubstring(r.text, """<td style="text-align: right;">(\w+)</td>""").group(1)
    dists_size_info[dist.key] = [dist.version, size]
    print(dists_size_info)
wf(json.dumps(dists_size_info),'dists_size_info.txt','w')
```

or you can get list at:

http://hastebin.com/qiconesoje.apache