# How to print size of an imported library?

Tags: python, package, size, libraries, filesize

Is there anyway to print out the size of a library in python? I've tried this method, but it doesn't work:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import fastai as fastai
>>> import pytorch as torch

>>> print(sys.getsizeof(torch))
88
>>> print(sys.getsizeof(fastai))
88
```

I think `fastai` is around 1.9 MB and `pytorch` is around 320 MB, but I want to confirm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know size of python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39096604/how-to-know-size-of-python-module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
import os, sys
dir_size = lambda dirpath:sum([(sum([os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, f)) for f in files]) + sum([dir_size(os.path.join(root, d)) for d in dirs])) for root, files, dirs in os.walk(dirpath)])
def module_size(module_name):
    for p in sys.path:
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(p, module_name)+'.py'):
            return f"{os.path.getsize(os.path.join(p, module_name)+'.py')/1024.0} KB"
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(p, module_name)):            
            return f'{dir_size(os.path.join(p, module_name))/1024.0} KB'
    return 'Module not installed.'

print(module_size('fastai'))
print(module_size('pytorch'))
```