# How can i determine the exact size of a type used by python

Tags: python

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(int)
436 #? does this mean int occupies 436 bytes .

>>> sys.getsizeof(1)
12 #12 bytes for int object, is this the memory requirement.
```

I thought int in python is represented by 4 bytes, why is it reporting 12 bytes

Please someone explain why is it reporting 12 bytes when int uses just 4 bytes

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I profile memory usage in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552744/how-do-i-profile-memory-usage-in-python)

Comment: Also, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/python-memory-profiler). Basically, the tool linked there (Heapy) is part of a thesis on memory profiling in Python. If you really want to know, check that out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, an `int` instance takes up 12 bytes on your system. Integers (like any object) have attributes, i.e. pointers to other objects, which take up additional memory space beyond that used by the object's own value. So 4 bytes for the integer's value, 4 bytes for a pointer to `__class__` (otherwise, Python wouldn't know what type the object belonged to and how to start resolving attribute names that are inherited from the `int` class and its parents), and another 4 for the object's reference count, which is used by the garbage collector.

The type `int` occupies 436 bytes on your system, which will be pointers to the various methods and other attributes of the `int` class and whatever other housekeeping information Python requires for the class. The `int` class is written in C in the standard Python implementation; you could go look at the source code and see what's in there.

Comment: Python does not store (sufficiently small) integers by using a special bit in the object pointer as some other languages (ruby, some lisps) do, so they use up rather a lot of memory for plain ints. If 12 bytes is too much for you, and you want to store large arrays of ints, look into numpy's special arrays.

Comment: @eryksun: Either think about how dreadful the average performance of `array.append` would be if it didn't over-allocate, or read the source (arraymodule.c).

Comment: @kindall: Your answer is specific to Python 2.x. Consider extending it to cover 3.x.

Comment: It's not really over-allocating if an integer object really takes 12 bytes. Special containers (array and numpy) save on that by storing C *int values and only convert to python objects on the interface.

Comment: @eryksun: How do you test whether a container over-allocates or not??

Comment: @eryksun: In 32-bit Python, a list of anything will take 36 + n * 4 * (1 + list_overallocation_factor(n)) for the list itself, and n * getsizeof(average_instance) for the payload. In Python 2.x, the marginal cost of an `int` will be zero if it's a very small int or already referenced, otherwise 12 bytes. The cost of a Python 3.x `int` (or a 2.x `long`) will be, if not zero, dependant on the size of the number (14 bytes up to 65535, then 16, increasing by 16 bits for every 15 bits of payload). What size instances of what type(s) are you measuring with what tool(s) on which py version(s)?

Comment: @eryksun: yes I was speaking of int object size only, list/array overallocation is not something I am concerned about. This question revolves around the size of int objects, and container overallocation to improve append/concatenation performance is slightly off topic. I only mentioned containers because some special ones can store integers with *less* than getsizeof(int) per number by C optimization.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for [`sys.getsizeof`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof):

> `getsizeof()` calls the object’s `__sizeof__` method and adds an additional garbage collector overhead if the object is managed by the garbage collector.

That might be why `sys.getsizeof(1)` is giving you 12 bytes.  As for your first line, keep in mind what the `int` object is:

```
>>> int
<type 'int'>
```

`int` is the integer type itself, and not an integer.  An integer in python actually takes up as many bytes as it needs (which is why you don't need to worry about overflow), while the type is where all that functionality is handled.  I believe this distinction is only valid for built-in types, and for user-defined objects the type itself is probably of a similar size as an instance of that type.