# The best way to base64 encode the last 6k bits of a python integer

Tags: python, python-2.7, binary, base64

I illustrate a case for where k = 2 (so, the bottom 12 digits)

```
import base64

# Hi
# 7 - 34
# 000111 - 100010
# 0001 - 1110 - 0010 = 0x1E2 = 482

# 1
integer = int(bin(482)[-12:] + '0' * 20, 2)
encoded = base64.b64encode(base64.b16decode('{0:08X}'.format(integer)))
print encoded

# 2
encoded = base64.b64encode(base64.b16decode('{0:08X}'.format(482 << 20)))
print encoded
```

Both output HiAAAA== as desired

An ideone link for your convenience: http://ideone.com/O73kQs

Intuitively these are very clear, and I'm favoring #2 by quite a bit.
One thing that "irks" me about #1, is that if the integers in python are not 32 bits, then I'm in trouble.
How can I get the proper size of an int? (total python newbie question?) (edit: yes, apparently a newbie-ish question [How can i determine the exact size of a type used by python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779207/how-can-i-determine-the-exact-size-of-a-type-used-by-python))

It would be nice, however, if there was a way to simply do something like

```
encoded = base64.b64encode('{0:08X}'.format(482 << 20))
```

Moreover, how can I go from

```
bin(1)
```

which equals

```
'0b1'
```

to the actual binary literal

```
0b1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can go from bin back with int , which takes an optional 2nd parameter that is base

```
int(bin(18)[2:],2)
```

since you use this earlier you must know about it ... so I only assume you mean something else by binary literal than its integer representation ... although for the life of me im not sure what that is...

you can do

```
print 0b1
```

and see that the actual repr is the decimal value ...

to get the last 12 bits of an int

```
my_int = 482
k=2
mask = int("1"*(6*k),2)
last_bits = my_int & mask
```

then you can just shift it 20 or whatever ...

first get the last 12 bits as demonstrated above

```
 import struct
 print struct.pack('H',last_bits)
 print struct.pack('H',0b100001)
```

alternatively you could

```
 def get_chars(int_val):
     while int_val > 0:
         yield chr(int_val & 0xFF)
         int_val <<= 8 

 print repr("".join(get_chars(last_bits)))
```

Comment: I guess I was just hopeful that something like "str(0b100001)" Could give me "!" and not "100001". =/

Comment: No, because I was looking to turn it into a string and not just a character (which I suppose I could achieve by list comprehension?)

Basically, my question is... what's the best way to interpret the least significant 12 bits of a python integer (and however many zeroes I need for padding) as an ascii string?

Comment: as an aside ints will just allocate more space if they excede a size so you cannot be sure its 32bits ... you could force it by anding it with 0xFFFFFFFF

Comment: see my edit ... keep in mind it will only ever make 2 characters I think

Comment: I added a second method that should be able to produxe longer strings for bigger values ...