# memory_profiler display only function level results

Tags: python-2.7, memory-profiling

I am using the [memory_profiler for python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) as follows:

```
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile
def my_func():
   ...
```

And run it normally.

Output looks like this (taken from docs):

```
Line #    Mem usage  Increment   Line Contents
==============================================
     3                           @profile
     4      5.97 MB    0.00 MB   def my_func():
     5     13.61 MB    7.64 MB       a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
     6    166.20 MB  152.59 MB       b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
     7     13.61 MB -152.59 MB       del b
     8     13.61 MB    0.00 MB       return a
```

Though I'd like it to be shortened to function level and look akin to this:

```
Line #    Mem usage  Increment    Max         Line Contents
==============================================================
     4      13.61 MB    7.64 MB   166.20 MB     my_func()
     20     23.26 MB    9.65 MB   56.20 MB     my_second_func()
```

Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850995/tracking-maximum-memory-usage-by-a-python-function

Answer (score 1):

You can always define a third function

```
@profile
def my_third_func():
    my_func()
    my_second_func()
```

and profile this function. This should yield the output you are looking for.

Otherwise, if you are only interested in the maximum memory consumption of the different functions, [mprof](http://fa.bianp.net/blog/2014/plot-memory-usage-as-a-function-of-time/) provides a handy visual plot for that.