# numpy fails to resize large matrix

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory, openpyxl

I use `openpyxl` and `numpy` to read large excel files. The code looks like

```
W = load_workbook(fname, read_only = True)
p = W.worksheets[0]
a=[]
m = p.max_row
n = p.max_column
for row in p.iter_rows():
    for k in row:
        a.append(k.value)

# convert list a to matrix (for example 5*6)
aa= np.resize(a, [m, n])
```

for medium sized files (4MB excel file with 16000 rows and 50 columns) they work fine. However for large files (21B with 100000 rows and 50 columns), `numpy` fails with memory error. There is memory available on the system.

1- How can I find how much memory it took while resizing to matrix?

2- How can I increase the memory (something like heap size in java)?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exread.py", line 26, in <module>
    aa= np.resize(a, [m, n])
  File "C:\Users\m.naderan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packa
ges\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 1121, in resize
    a = ravel(a)
  File "C:\Users\m.naderan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 1468, in ravel
    return asanyarray(a).ravel(order=order)
  File "C:\Users\m.naderan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 583, in asanyarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
MemoryError
```

Comment: What's the point to this use of `resize`?  It is rarely needed.  Use np.array to make  an array from a list.

Comment: Well I thought it will neatly resize the array to m*n. So please let me know how to use `np.array`./

Comment: You might just use `aa = np.array([[i.value for i in j] for j in p.rows])` instead of everything except the first two lines.

Comment: @Nyps: Sorry, I didn't understand. Can you please explain in an answer what does that statement do exactly?

Comment: This reads in all values in your worksheet directly to the numpy array. It loops through all elements in all rows. Just try replacing the code.

Comment: Like this: `W = load_workbook(fname, read_only = True)`,   `p = W.worksheets[0]`,   `aa = np.array([[i.value for i in j] for j in p.rows])` as your whole code.

Comment: Still I get memory error :(

Answer (score 0):

1. The most pragmatic way to check the memory usage of an operation would probably be to just watch `top`/`htop` if you're on a Unix system. Someone did post a Python [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850995/tracking-maximum-memory-usage-by-a-python-function) to this 5 years ago.
2. I may be wrong on this, but I think there is no restriction on the memory usage of a Python kernel by default, i.e. `MemoryError`s really only happen when there genuinely isn't enough available memory on your entire system (I've run scripts consuming over 50GB of memory before).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation contains a [clear example of how to convert a worksheet to a dataframe](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html#converting-a-worksheet-to-a-dataframe). This easier to use and more reliable than your own code so why not use it?

Comment: The examples are not clear. What is the need for data frame and why we should use it and what will happen if we don't use that? I just want to read the cells row by row