# Using a function to call another function

Tags: python, memory-profiling

I am attempting to use the `memory_profiler` package. Example code below:

```
from memory_profiler import memory_usage
from time import sleep

def f():
    # a function that with growing
    # memory consumption
    a = [0] * 1000
    sleep(.1)
    b = a * 100
    sleep(.1)
    c = b * 100
    return a

mem_usage = memory_usage(f)
print('Memory usage (in chunks of .1 seconds): %s' % mem_usage)
print('Maximum memory usage: %s' % max(mem_usage))
```

The problem I am facing is that my actual function I want to try this on takes arguments.

```
def my_func(df1, df2):
    new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
    return new_df
```

Is there a way to create a shell function that runs my real function so that I can use this package?

```
def shell_function():
    new_df = my_func(df1, df1)
    return new_df
```

Code is from 2nd answer on this post: [Tracking *maximum* memory usage by a Python function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850995/tracking-maximum-memory-usage-by-a-python-function)

Comment: That looks like it should work. Have you tried passed `shell_function` to `memory_usage`?

Comment: Also note from the comments under that answer: "In case when function `f` has arguments `args` and keywords arguments `kw` you can invoke it with `memory_usage((f, args, kw))`"

Comment: Ah I was doing something silly, great this works now. Thanks!