# Amount of memory used in a function?

Tags: python, algorithm, memory-management

Which python module can I use to calculate the amount of memory spent executing a function? I'm using [`memory_profiler`](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/), but it shows the amount of memory spent by each line of the algorithm, in this case I want one that shows the total amount spent.

Comment: Is this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9850995/3768871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tracemalloc` to do what *memory_profiller* does automatically.  It's a little unfriendly but I think it does what you want to do pretty well.
Just follow the code snippet below.

```
import tracemalloc

def myFucn():
    tracemalloc.start()
    ## Your code
    print( tracemalloc..get_traced_memory())
    tracemalloc.stop()
```

> The output is given in form of (current,peak),i.e, current memory is the memory the code is currently using and peak memory is the maximum space the program used while executing.

The code is from [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/monitoring-memory-usage-of-a-running-python-program/). Check it out for more info. Also, there are a couple of other methods to trace the memory explained inside the link. Make sure to check it out.