# Find the memory size of a set of strings vs. set of bytestrings

Tags: python, memory, set, ram

Edit: the answer from [Memory usage of a list of millions of strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71233311/memory-usage-of-a-list-of-millions-of-strings-in-python/71234855#71234855) can be adapted to sets too.

---

By analyzing the RAM usage on my machine (with the process manager), I noticed that a set of millions of strings like `'abcd'` takes much less memory than a set of millions of bytes `b'abcd'` (Edit: I was wrong, it was due to an error elsewhere). I would like to test this:

```
import random, string, sys
randomstring = lambda length: ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(length))
s1 = {randomstring(10) for i in range(100_000)}
s2 = {randomstring(50) for i in range(100_000)}
s3 = {randomstring(10).encode() for i in range(100_000)} 
s4 = {randomstring(50).encode() for i in range(100_000)} 
print(sys.getsizeof(s1), sys.getsizeof(s2), sys.getsizeof(s3), sys.getsizeof(s4))
```

but here it always gives the same size: `4194528` whereas the size should vary with a factor x5, and probably be different for the string vs bytes case.

**How to measure the memory size taken by these sets and all its elements?**

Note: I know that finding the whole memory taken by a structure is not easy in Python (see also [In-memory size of a Python structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331471/in-memory-size-of-a-python-structure)), because we need to take in account all the linked elements.

**TL;DR**: Is there a tool in Python to automatically measure the memory size of a set + the memory taken by the internal references (pointers?), the hashtable buckets, the elements (strings here) that are hosted in the set...? In short: every byte that is necessary for this set of strings. Does such a memory measurement tool exist?

Comment: Strings can contain multibyte characters. But if all the characters are ASCII, they just take 1 byte, just like the elements of byte strings.. I can't think of any reason why the memory use should be different in this case.

Comment: There's probably very little difference between a character string and byte string. They both contain a reference to the class object (just like most Python objects), the length, and the raw data. The Python interpreter has built-in code for processing strings, but that doesn't affect the data representation.

Comment: @Barmar I now understand your first comment was about strings vs. byte-strings. (I thought it was about size of byte-string vs. number of char, but I misread). Yeah you're right, there is no much diff betwen strings vs. bytes, finally (after new tests) just a little bit less for bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.getsizeof` does not measure the size of the full target data structure. It only measure the memory taken by the set object which contains **references** to strings/bytes objects. The **references are not included in the returned memory consumption** (ie. it does *not walk recursively* in each object of the target data structure). A reference takes typically 8 bytes on a 64-bit platform and a CPython set is not as compact as a list: it is implemented like a [hash-table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) with many *buckets* and some buckets are unused. In fact, this is mandatory for this data structure to be fast (in general, the *occupancy* should be 50%-90%). Moreover, each bucket contains a hash which usually takes 8 bytes.

The string themselves take much more space than a bucket (at least on my machine):

```py
sys.getsizeof(randomstring(50))           # 99
sys.getsizeof(randomstring(50).encode())  # 83
```

On my machine, it turns out that CPython strings are 16 bytes bigger than bytes.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a tool in Python to automatically measure the size of a set + the references + the hashtable buckets + the elements (strings here) that are hosted in the set?

Comment: You can check the memory taken by the Python process (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850995/tracking-maximum-memory-usage-by-a-python-function) post for example). This is probably the most accurate solution to find an upper bound of the memory consumption. There are parts of the allocated memory that CPython cannot track. For example, Numpy arrays are allocated using the C allocator so CPython is not aware of that. This applies to many C-based libraries. Note that this is an upper bound since some allocators are conservative: they do not release memory to the OS directly.

Comment: Note also that reference can form cycles so this is also why tracking the total amount of memory is a bit tricky in practice. Not to mention some references can appear several time in the same list. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33978/find-out-how-much-memory-is-being-used-by-an-object-in-python) related post that provides more information.

Comment: You're right @JérômeRichard, so I'll probably continue using [this simple upper bound](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21632554/1422096) as an indicator of the size of the multiple-gigabyte set. During my tests, I only have one big set and nothing else in my code, this is a good estimation I think.