# Pytorch: Why is the memory occupied by the `tensor` variable so small?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor, numpy-ndarray

In Pytorch 1.0.0, I found that a `tensor` variable occupies very small memory. I wonder how it stores so much data.
Here's the code.

```
a = np.random.randn(1, 1, 128, 256)
b = torch.tensor(a, device=torch.device('cpu'))

a_size = sys.getsizeof(a)
b_size = sys.getsizeof(b)
```

`a_size` is 262288. `b_size` is 72.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The answer is in two parts. From the documentation of [`sys.getsizeof`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof), firstly

> All built-in objects will return correct results, but this does not have to hold true for third-party extensions as it is implementation specific.

so it could be that for tensors `__sizeof__` is undefined or defined differently than you would expect - this function is not something you can rely on. Secondly

> Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.

which means that if the `torch.Tensor` object merely holds a reference to the actual memory, this won't show in `sys.getsizeof`. This is indeed the case, if you check the size of the underlying [storage](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.Tensor.storage.html#torch.Tensor.storage) instead, you will see the expected number

```
import torch, sys
b = torch.randn(1, 1, 128, 256, dtype=torch.float64)
sys.getsizeof(b)
>> 72
sys.getsizeof(b.storage())
>> 262208
```

Note: I am setting `dtype` to `float64` explicitly, because that is the default `dtype` in `numpy`, whereas `torch` uses `float32` by default.

Comment: Really great answer, would give another +1 for the pointer towards `storage`. Super helpful to know!

Comment: Thanks, this worked! For the memory of a slice of a tensor, `storage()` will return the memory size of the whole tensor. Thus, we need to clone/copy the slice first.

Answer (score 1):

if you want get the size of tensor or network in cuda,you could use this code to calculate it size:

```py
import torch

device = 'cuda:0'

# before
torch._C._cuda_clearCublasWorkspaces()
memory_before = torch.cuda.memory_allocated(device)

# your tensor or network
data5 = torch.randn((10000,100),device=device)

# after
memory_after = torch.cuda.memory_allocated(device)
latent_size = memory_after - memory_before

latent_size
# 4000256
```

get idea from this:https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/ee28b865ee9c87cce4db0011987baf8d125cc857/torch/distributed/pipeline/sync/_balance/profile.py#L102