# PyTorch conversion between tensor and numpy array: the addition operation

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I am following the [60-minute blitz on PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/tensor_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-tensor-tutorial-py) but have a question about conversion of a numpy array to a tensor. Tutorial example [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/tensor_tutorial.html#converting-numpy-array-to-torch-tensor).

This piece of code:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.ones(5)
b = torch.from_numpy(a)
np.add(a, 1, out=a)
print(a)
print(b)
```

yields

> [2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
>
> tensor([2., 2., 2., 2., 2.], dtype=torch.float64)

However

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.ones(5)
b = torch.from_numpy(a)
a = a + 1 #the diff is here 
print(a)
print(b)
```

yields

> [2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
>
> tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], dtype=torch.float64)

**Why are the outputs different?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This actually has little to do with PyTorch. Compare

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones(5)
b = a
```

followed by either

```
np.add(a, 1, out=a)
print(b)
```

or

```
a = a + 1
print(b)
```

There is a difference between `np.add(a, 1, out=a)` and `a = a + 1`. In the former you retain the same object (array) `a` with different values (`2` instead of `1`); in the latter you get a *new* array, which is bound to the same variable name `a` and has values of `2`. However, the "original" `a` is discarded and unless something else (`b`) points to it, would be deallocated. In other words, the first operation is in-place and the latter out-of-place. Since `b` holds on to the array originally found at `a`, reassigning `a + 1` to `a` does not affect the value of `b`. An alternative in-place mutation syntax would be

```
a[:] = a + 1
print(b)
```

Regarding PyTorch, it's very simple. `from_numpy` creates a tensor which aliases an actual object (array), so it is equivalent to the `b = a` line in my first snippet. The tensor will track the changes in the array named `a` at the point of calling, rather than the changes of what the name `a` points to.

Comment: b = a, followed by id(a), id(b) shows that they are in fact sharing the same memory location. However in the snippet above (b= a.numpy()), if you do id(a) and id(b) it gives different values. How are they sharing the memory location when id gives different values?

Comment: @Ambareesh `a.numpy()` creates a tensor which shares the contiguous array holding tensor/array elements, but has different "python wrappers" which keep the strides etc. In other words, `a.numpy()` and `a` are different objects which both contain a pointer to the same memory region. For the PyTorch side of things, you can refer to my answer to [why tensors appear so small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361763/pytorch-why-is-the-memory-occupied-by-the-tensor-variable-so-small/54365012#54365012).

Answer (score 1):

My take on this :

When you do

```
b = torch.from_numpy(a)
```

b and a points to the same place in memory. From the doc :

```
Converting a torch Tensor to a numpy array and vice versa is a breeze. The torch Tensor and numpy array will share their underlying memory locations, and changing one will change the other.
```

When you do

```
np.add(a, 1, out=a)
```

You modify `a` in place while when you do

```
a = a+1
```

You create a new array (named `a` as well), but that new array doesn't share underlying memory locations with b, so you're not affecting b.