# Understanding size of class, namedtuple and __slots__ in Python 3.7

Tags: python, class, documentation, python-3.7

After watching Nina Zahkarenko's Python Memory Management talk at Pycon2016 ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6u5rhUQ6dU)), it seemed like the dunder method `__slots__` was a tool to reduce object size and speed up attribute lookup.

My expectation was that a normal class would be the largest, while a `__slots__`/`namedtuple` approach would save space. However, a quick experiment with `sys.getsizeof()` seems to suggest otherwise:

```py
from collections import namedtuple
from sys import getsizeof

class Rectangle:
   '''A class based Rectangle, with a full __dict__'''
   def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      self.width = width
      self.height = height

class SlotsRectangle:
   '''A class based Rectangle with __slots__ defined for attributes'''
   __slots__ = ('x', 'y', 'width', 'height')

   def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      self.width = width
      self.height = height

NamedTupleRectangle = namedtuple('Rectangle', ('x', 'y', 'width', 'height'))
NamedTupleRectangle.__doc__ = 'A rectangle as an immutable namedtuple'

print(f'Class: {getsizeof(Rectangle(1,2,3,4))}')
print(f'Slots: {getsizeof(SlotsRectangle(1,2,3,4))}')
print(f'Named Tuple: {getsizeof(NamedTupleRectangle(1,2,3,4))}')
```

Terminal Output:

```sh
$ python3.7 example.py
Class: 56
Slots: 72
Named Tuple: 80
```

What is going on here? From the docs on Python's [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) it appears that descriptors are used for `__slots__` which would add function overhead to classes implementing it. However, why are the results so heavily skewed towards a normal class?

Channeling my inner Raymond H.: there has to be a harder way!

Comment: `getsizeof` isn't reporting the size of data structures referenced by the class object; only the class object itself.

Answer (score 2):

The function `sys.getsizeof()` is probably not doing what you think it does; it does not work for complex objects, like custom classes.

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30316760/9225671) for a method to calculate the memory size of objects; maybe it helps you.
I copied the code from that answer in here, but the full explanation is in the answer I linked.

```
import sys
from numbers import Number
from collections import Set, Mapping, deque

try: # Python 2
    zero_depth_bases = (basestring, Number, xrange, bytearray)
    iteritems = 'iteritems'
except NameError: # Python 3
    zero_depth_bases = (str, bytes, Number, range, bytearray)
    iteritems = 'items'

def getsize(obj_0):
    """Recursively iterate to sum size of object & members."""
    _seen_ids = set()
    def inner(obj):
        obj_id = id(obj)
        if obj_id in _seen_ids:
            return 0
        _seen_ids.add(obj_id)
        size = sys.getsizeof(obj)
        if isinstance(obj, zero_depth_bases):
            pass # bypass remaining control flow and return
        elif isinstance(obj, (tuple, list, Set, deque)):
            size += sum(inner(i) for i in obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, Mapping) or hasattr(obj, iteritems):
            size += sum(inner(k) + inner(v) for k, v in getattr(obj, iteritems)())
        # Check for custom object instances - may subclass above too
        if hasattr(obj, '__dict__'):
            size += inner(vars(obj))
        if hasattr(obj, '__slots__'): # can have __slots__ with __dict__
            size += sum(inner(getattr(obj, s)) for s in obj.__slots__ if hasattr(obj, s))
        return size
    return inner(obj_0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Ralf, I believe `sys.getsizeof()` is fulfilling my use case though. My rectangle object contains four variables which can refer to objects elsewhere on Python's managed heap. The memory footprint of `x` is irrelevant to me, it could be a `list[]` with thousands of elements. It was my understanding that the attribute `x` was only a reference. What I expected to see was reduced memory overhead when using __slots__ compared to a class without.

Answer (score 2):

There is more compact variant with [recordclass](https://pypi.org/project/recordclass) library:

```
from recordclass import dataobject

class Rectangle(dataobject):
   x:int
   y:int
   width:int
   height:int

>>> r = Rectangle(1,2,3,4)
>>> print(sys.getsizeof(r))
48
```

It has less memory footprint than `__slots__`-based one because it doesn't participate in cyclic garbage collection (Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_GC flag doesn't set, so `PyGC_Head` (24 bytes [<3.8] and 16 bytes [>=3.8]) doesn't need at all).

Answer (score 1):

"Channeling my inner Raymond H," +1

So the thing about slots is, you have to read [about slots](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots).

The other thing is, they do affect `class` size:

```
print(f'(Class) Class: {getsizeof(Rectangle)}') # 1056
print(f'(Class) Slots: {getsizeof(SlotsRectangle)}') # 888
```

Cool. Now let's say we add a field to the Rectangle class:

```
rect = Rectangle(1,2,3,4)
rect.extra_field = dict() # wild right?
print(f'(Object) Class: {getsizeof(rect)}') # still 56
```

So you can "count" the resources "your using" (in the form of instance variables) and the slots rectangle would be `112` and the non-slots rectangle would be 112 as well...

However, we know this to not be the case as we would expect the regular rectangle to be at least `352` because we added a `dict` to it.

Slots prevent you from being able to do this and thus provide a way of constraining resource usage.

Check out this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53705610/8624508), it seems like it might work fairly well for you use case. Running it on the slots rectangle and regular rectangle yields `152` and `352` respectively.

Also, if you're really into trying to optimize your code and minimize resource use come on over to the rust/c/c++ side of the house.