# Scikit learn memory error on predicting through GuassianNB

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I am using GuassianNB of Sci-kit learn for my classification.After fitting my data and on predicting ,it throws memory error.

```
clf1=GaussianNB() 
clf1.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred1=clf1.predict(imgarray)
```

**where:**

1. X_train is an array of size(1413,2)
2. y_train is an array of size (1413,)
3. imgarray size is (9000000,2)

**Error :**

[image: Error thrown]

**Other Details:**

SCi-Kit learn version: 0.15, Windows 7 32 bit, Python 2.7, pydev,RAM 4 GB

I have tried to change the version and other stuffs but problem continues. Is my imgarray too big?.I shall be thankful for the help and advises.

Comment: Is your `imgarray` size is `9000000`?

Comment: @badc0re ...yes 9000000 rows with 2 columns consisting of R and G band of image pixels

Comment: Well i think it is a lot for 4gb machine, imagine if you have 10.000 images (which is not a lot) how much memory will it require? I think it is good to see how to use some image processing techniques in order to reduce your vector size.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `imgarray` on its own is enough to crash a 4GB machine:

```
In [3]: a = np.zeros((9000000,2))
In [4]: a.nbytes
Out[4]: 144000000
```

which is about 137MB.  Are you holding any other large arrays is memory? It's hard to tell without looking at your code. Could you post a complete an runnable piece of code so we can have a closer look?

Also, you can have a look at this question to learn how to do [memory profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552744/how-do-i-profile-memory-usage-in-python).