# psutil error on macos

Tags: python, macos, macos-sierra

```
def showMemTime(when='Resources'):
  global maxmem
  # memory and time measurement
  process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
  mem = process.get_memory_info()[0] / float(2 ** 20)
  maxmem = max(maxmem, mem)
  ts = process.get_cpu_times()
  sys.stderr.write("{when:<20}: {mb:4.0f} MB (max {maxmb:4.0f} MB), {user:4.1f} s user, {system:4.1f} s system\n".format(
    when=when, mb=mem, maxmb=maxmem, user=ts.user, system=ts.system))
```

I'm trying to use the code above. But i get "AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute 'get_memory_info'" I'm on Python 2.7, psutil 5.0.0 and macOS Sierra

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process class doesn't have a method named `get_memory_info`. It has `memory_full_info()` and `memory_info()` [psutil.Process](http://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=memory_info#psutil.Process.memory_info)

Answer (score 0):

additional info to metmirr's this has been removed from macos, may thats why people still run into this.

> Changed in version 5.6.0: removed macOS support because inherently
>   broken (see issue #1291)