# Measuring number of floating-point operations in python algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, profiling, microcontroller

I have a data processing algorithm implemented in Python 2.7, and I need to move it on an embedded system (let it be microcontroller or a more advanced board). To choose the hardware I must know how many floating-point operations are performed and how much memory is used in total.

How to determine these efficiently?

Answer (score -1):

To count the number of operations, you can do something like

```
class N:

    ops = 0

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __add__(self, rhs):
        N.ops += 1
        return N(self.x + rhs.x)

result = N(1) + N(2)
assert result.x == 3
assert N.ops == 1
```

and replace all your floats with N(float)s.

For memory usage see [How do I profile memory usage in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552744/how-do-i-profile-memory-usage-in-python)