# Sci-kit learn: How to measure time and space complexity of machine learning algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, time, scikit-learn, time-complexity

I want to measure time and space complexity foreach algorithm LR and NB using python scikit learn.

```
models = []
models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression()))
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
seed = 7
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
for name, m in models:
    start_time = time.time()
    results = cross_val_score(m, X, Y, cv=kfold)
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print(name)
    print("Accuracy:", results.mean()*100.0,'% Time:', elapsed_time)
    results = 0
    start_time=0
   elapsed_time=0
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I want to measure space complexity .

Comment: So you are looking for a way to measure memory usage of current process?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552744/how-do-i-profile-memory-usage-in-python