# How to check how much memory a Python program is using when running

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management

### In Python 3.x, how can we report how many memory a program is using?

I would like to compare different solutions to the same problem using consumed memory like metric.

By example, what is the consumed memory from:

```
import itertools

def queens ():
    for p in itertools.permutations (range (8) ):
        yield [x for x in enumerate (p) ]

for q in queens ():
    err = False
    for a, b in ( (a, b) for a in q for b in q if a [0] < b [0] ):
        if abs (a [0] - b [0] ) == abs (a [1] - b [1] ):
            err = True
            break
    if not err: print (q)
```

And what is the consumed memory from:

```
SIZE=8
A=[0] * SIZE  # Array solution
s=0  # Global variable to count 'solutions', you can delete it!
t=0  # Global variable to count recursion 'tests', you can delete it!

def test(queen, col):
    global t
    t+=1
    for i in range(1,queen):
        if(A[queen-i-1]==col): return 0     # Test vertical
        if(A[queen-i-1]==col-i): return 0   # Test diagonal 1 (\)
        if(A[queen-i-1]==col+i): return 0   # Test diagonal 2 (/)
    return 1

def play(queen):
    global s
    for col in range(1,SIZE+1):
        if(test(queen,col)):     # If I can play the queen...
            A[queen-1]=col       # Add queen to the solution Array
            if(queen==SIZE):     # If the last queen was played, this is a solution
                s+=1
                print("Solution: {}, {}, {}".format(s,t,A))
            else:
                play(queen+1);   # If not last queen, play the next one
            A[queen-1]=0         # Clean the solution Array

play(1)  # Start putting first queen
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some interesting links:

- [Monitoring memory usage of a running Python program](https://medium.com/survata-engineering-blog/monitoring-memory-usage-of-a-running-python-program-49f027e3d1ba)
- [tracemalloc — Trace memory allocations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html)
- [How do I profile memory usage in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552744/how-do-i-profile-memory-usage-in-python) (stack overflow)

In summary, one solution is:

```
import tracemalloc
tracemalloc.start()

#
# code to test here
#

current, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
print(f"Current memory usage is {current / 10**3}KB; Peak was {peak / 10**3}KB; Diff = {(peak - current) / 10**3}KB")
tracemalloc.stop()
```