# How to find memory usage with memory_profiler Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

At the end of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552744/how-do-i-profile-memory-usage-in-python) I found some code. I will put it here for convenience:

```
import memory_profiler as mp

def fun(n):
    tmp = []
    for i in range(n):
        tmp.extend(list(range(i*i)))
    return "XXXXX"

start_mem = mp.memory_usage(max_usage=True)
res = mp.memory_usage(proc=(fun, [100]), max_usage=True, retval=True) 
print('start mem', start_mem)
print('max mem', res[0][0])
print('used mem', res[0][0]-start_mem)
print('fun output', res[1])
```

But this doesn't work because res is not a double array, it is float number. Moreover, I don't understand how to check memory usage for many functions. I mean, would something like this work?

```
import memory_profiler as mp

def fun1(n):
    return "XXXXX"
def fun2(n):
    return "YYYYY"

methods = [
    'fun1(n)',
    'fun2(n)',
    ]

start_mem = mp.memory_usage(max_usage=True)
res = mp.memory_usage(proc=(methods[0], [100]), max_usage=True, retval=True) 
print('start mem', start_mem)
print('max mem', res[0][0])
print('used mem', res[0][0]-start_mem)
print('fun output', res[1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to complement Alok's answer.

`memory_usage` method takes tuple `(method, args, kwargs)`.

To find memory usage of a method and store value in variable, you can do this:

```
from memory_profiler import memory_usage


def foo(n):
    t = [list(range(i * i)) for i in range(n)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    memory = memory_usage((foo, (5,), {}))
    print(memory)
```

If you have multiple methods, you can put them in list and then iterate over it:

```
from memory_profiler import memory_usage


def foo(n):
    t = [list(range(i * i)) for i in range(n)]


def bar(n):
    t = [1 for i in range(n)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    methods = [foo, bar]
    memory = memory_usage((methods[0], (5,), {}))
```

Don't forget about using `memory_usage` in `if __name__ == '__main__':` or in other methods and don't forget about comma in `(5,)`. This code will throw two exceptions because of `__main__` and comma:

```
from memory_profiler import memory_usage


def foo(n):
    t = [list(range(i * i)) for i in range(n)]


def bar(n):
    t = [1 for i in range(n)]


functions = [foo, bar]
memory = memory_usage((functions[0], (5), {}))
```

Full information about `memory_usage` you can find in [documentation](https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler).

Answer (score 5):

Installing memory_profiler:

```
pip3 install -U memory_profiler
```

Sometimes it is useful to have full memory usage reports as a function of time (not line-by-line) of external processes (be it Python scripts or not). In this case, the executable mprof might be useful

To get the line by line profiling, add decorator ‘@profile’ in front of the def function.

```
from memory_profiler import profile
@profile
def my_func():
    a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
    b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
    del b
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_func()
```

After this save the .py file and run the below code in terminal.

```
mprof run perf_test_v1.py
```

This will show you the memory usage by every line of code.
To Plot the memory usage vs time through the below code.

```
mprof plot
```

The available commands for mprof are:

```
mprof run: running an executable, recording memory usage
mprof plot: plotting one the recorded memory usage (by default, the last one)
mprof list: listing all recorded memory usage files in a user-friendly way.
mprof clean: removing all recorded memory usage files.
mprof rm: removing specific recorded memory usage files
```

This would help you identify the bottlenecks in your codes and helps in optimizing the steps.

**To get time-based memory usage**

Execute the code passing the option -m memory_profiler to the python interpreter to load the memory_profiler module and print to stdout the line-by-line analysis. If the file name was example.py, this would result in:

```
$ python -m memory_profiler example.py
```

Comment: Is it possible to use mprof without terminal?

Comment: There are two ways you can run it :-

Comment: Sometimes it is useful to have full memory usage reports as a function of time (not line-by-line) of external processes (be it Python scripts or not). In this case, the executable mprof might be useful.

Comment: Execute the code passing the option -m memory_profiler to the python interpreter to load the memory_profiler module and print to stdout the line-by-line analysis. If the file name was example.py, this would result in:

$ python -m memory_profiler example.py

Comment: Added in the answer itself, please check it once

Comment: It is still terminal but I need something like this: `x = memory_profiler.memory_usage(fun1(10))`

Comment: There are other libraries which can help then like Guppy, Pympler etc.Try those they are also good