# Memory leak in python when defining dictionaries in functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a program with a function that needs to open big pickle files (a few GB), look at the obtained dictionary (dict), and return a partial view of it (a few elements). Curiously, the large amount of data opened by the function remains in memory.
So I did a few tests with the following code:

```
import numpy as np

def test_mem_1():
    data = np.random.random((2**27)) #1 GB
    input("Data generated, awaiting input to continue")
    return 4

def test_mem_2():
    keys = list(range(100000))
    lvls = list(range(10))
    data = {}
    for k in keys:
        data[k] = {}
        for lvl in lvls:
            data[k][lvl] = np.random.random(100) #1'000'000 X 8 = 800 MB
    input("Data generated, awaiting input to continue")
    data = None
    return 4

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = test_mem_1() 
    input("Tested mem 1, continue to test mem 2")
    a = test_mem_2()#Memory usage falls from 995 MB inside test_mem_1 to 855 MB when returned
    input("Finished")
    exit()
```

When running this experiment, the first test allocates 1 GB, then this data is freed as soon as the function returns. At the same time, the second test (working with a dict), first allocates 995 MB, then, when the function returns, only 140 MB are freed (resulting in a memory footprint, after test_mem_2, of 855 MB).
What is happening here? How can I free this memory?

---

**P.S.**

I have tried deleting the data in test_mem_2 in several methods: Not doing anything, using "del", assigning to a new dict, and (as in this example) assigning the reference to None

Comment: This is not a memory leak. [This is the way](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/653/546/4b2.jpg) that python handles memory. Give [this article](https://stackify.com/python-garbage-collection/) a read.

Comment: @EdoAkse, Thanks for the interesting read. Unfortunately,  I fail to see how my problem falls inside what's written: I don't see any cyclic reference, and the reference count should drop to 0, as soon as the "data" object is de-referenced. What am I missing?

Comment: The thing is the garbage hasn't been collected yet. Running the same method multiple times should show the garbage being collected. Garbage collection has an impact on performance so its not done when the object is freed.

Comment: @EdoAkse ok but then why the data from test_mem_1 are freed instantaneously? 
Moreover, I've tried introducing a mock long work after running test_mem_2 and the memory does not get cleaned. At the same time, if I call test_mem_2 again, it goes through the same cycle, not freeing memory but increasing it to 995 MB and then recover it back at 8XX MB (XX because at every run is slightly bigger than 855 MB). So for how long I wait after, those 855 MB are freed only when python terminate

Comment: You *can* force garbage collection, but you **should not**. There are circumstances where you *need* to do this, but unless you actually are in this scenario, you **should not**. Python isn't like `c`. Garbage collection is automagic in python. Unless you actually have a good reason to mess with it, don't. From your own statement you can surmize that you actually have the memory available if needed, it's just that python is slightly lazy in collecting it (due to the performance impact of the collection itself. (ps I'm not trying to be a d*ck here, just trying to make my point clear )

Comment: [The article](https://stackify.com/python-garbage-collection/) I linked in my first comment should show you how to perform the garbage collection if you really want to do this manually, but I highly recommend not doing this...

Comment: @EdoAkse, No problem, you don't even sound like a d*ck, just someone explaining their position. Thanks for the read. I will try to find a workaround I guess (due to useless details for this question, I can't just wait for this lazy GC, the process gets terminated after a while due to lack of mem). If you are interested, post your answer (with some more details) I will accept it tomorrow (To give space for some other opinion, maybe)

Comment: ` the process gets terminated after a while due to lack of mem` --> this actually sounds like a memory leak 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer after comment discussion.**

Memory management is handled by python itself using Garbage Collection. Normally you should not touch this at all. Garbage collection is automagic in python. Unless you actually have a good reason to mess with it, don't.

However, you can force garbage collection, which can be usefull if you are dealing with a limited resource system fe.

I've combined your code with a function to get the memory usage which I've shamelessly stolen from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45679009/9267296), and I implemented the most basic garbage collection...

By running the `loopity()` multiple times I've not had it crash yet.

Note that I *did* add a `data = None` in `test_mem_1()`

**file: memleak.py**

```py
import numpy as np
import sys
import gc
import tracemalloc
import linecache
import os


tracemalloc.start()


def display_top(snapshot, key_type='lineno', limit=3, where=''):
    #
    #
    #  Shamelessly stolen from:
    #  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45679009/9267296
    #
    #  I replaced all old string formatting with f-strings
    #
    #
    print('======================================================================')
    if where != '':
        print(f'Printing stats:\n    {where}')
        print('======================================================================')
    

    snapshot = snapshot.filter_traces((
        tracemalloc.Filter(False, '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'),
        tracemalloc.Filter(False, '<unknown>'),
    ))
    top_stats = snapshot.statistics(key_type)

    print(f'Top {limit} lines')
    for index, stat in enumerate(top_stats[:limit], 1):
        frame = stat.traceback[0]
        # replace '/path/to/module/file.py' with 'module/file.py'
        filename = os.sep.join(frame.filename.split(os.sep)[-2:])
        print(f'#{index}: {filename}:{frame.lineno}: {stat.size / 1024:.1f} KiB')
        line = linecache.getline(frame.filename, frame.lineno).strip()
        if line:
            print(f'    {line}')

    other = top_stats[limit:]
    if other:
        size = sum(stat.size for stat in other)
        print(f'{len(other)} other: {size / 1024:.1f} KiB')
    total = sum(stat.size for stat in top_stats)
    print()
    print(f'=====> Total allocated size: {total / 1024:.1f} KiB')
    print()


def test_mem_1():
    display_top(tracemalloc.take_snapshot(), where='test_mem_1: start')

    data = np.random.random((2**27)) #1 GB
    display_top(tracemalloc.take_snapshot(), where='test_mem_1: data generated')

    input('Data generated, awaiting input to continue')
    data = None
    display_top(tracemalloc.take_snapshot(), where='test_mem_1: data == None')

    gc.collect()
    display_top(tracemalloc.take_snapshot(), where='test_mem_1: gc collected')

    return 4


def test_mem_2():
    display_top(tracemalloc.take_snapshot(), where='test_mem_2: start')

    keys = list(range(100000))
    lvls = list(range(10))
    display_top(tracemalloc.take_snapshot(), where='test_mem_2: lists generated')

    data = {}
    for k in keys:
        data[k] = {}
        for lvl in lvls:
            data[k][lvl] = np.random.random(100) #1'000'000 X 8 = 800 MB
    display_top(tracemalloc.take_snapshot(), where='test_mem_2: np data generated')

    input('Data generated, awaiting input to continue')
    data = None
    display_top(tracemalloc.take_snapshot(), where='test_mem_2: data == None')
 
    gc.collect()
    display_top(tracemalloc.take_snapshot(), where='test_mem_2: gc collected')

    return 4


def loopity():
    # added this logic to be able to run multiple times.
    # stops when input for finished != ''
    inp = ''
    while inp == '':
        display_top(tracemalloc.take_snapshot(), where='loopity: start')
        a = test_mem_1() 
        display_top(tracemalloc.take_snapshot(), where='loopity: test_mem_1 done')
        input('Tested mem 1, continue to test mem 2')

        a = test_mem_2()
        display_top(tracemalloc.take_snapshot(), where='loopity: test_mem_2 done')
        inp = input('Finished')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loopity()
```

this is the output from a Windows box running python 3.8.10 (*don't ask*):

```
======================================================================
Printing stats:
    loopity: start
======================================================================
Top 3 lines
#1: .\memleak.py:93: 0.1 KiB
    def loopity():
#2: .\memleak.py:69: 0.1 KiB
    def test_mem_2():
#3: .\memleak.py:53: 0.1 KiB
    def test_mem_1():
1 other: 0.1 KiB

=====> Total allocated size: 0.5 KiB

======================================================================
Printing stats:
    test_mem_1: start
======================================================================
Top 3 lines
#1: lib\linecache.py:137: 8.3 KiB
    lines = fp.readlines()
#2: .\memleak.py:39: 1.2 KiB
    line = linecache.getline(frame.filename, frame.lineno).strip()
#3: lib\tracemalloc.py:509: 1.2 KiB
    statistics.sort(reverse=True, key=Statistic._sort_key)
59 other: 20.4 KiB

=====> Total allocated size: 31.1 KiB

======================================================================
Printing stats:
    test_mem_1: data generated
======================================================================
Top 3 lines
#1: .\memleak.py:56: 1048576.3 KiB
    data = np.random.random((2**27)) #1 GB
#2: lib\linecache.py:137: 63.9 KiB
    lines = fp.readlines()
#3: lib\tracemalloc.py:65: 3.8 KiB
    return (self.size, self.count, self.traceback)
59 other: 26.3 KiB

=====> Total allocated size: 1048670.3 KiB

Data generated, awaiting input to continue
======================================================================
Printing stats:
    test_mem_1: data == None
======================================================================
Top 3 lines
#1: lib\linecache.py:137: 63.8 KiB
    lines = fp.readlines()
#2: lib\tracemalloc.py:532: 5.8 KiB
    traces = _get_traces()
#3: lib\tracemalloc.py:65: 3.9 KiB
    return (self.size, self.count, self.traceback)
66 other: 25.2 KiB

=====> Total allocated size: 98.6 KiB

======================================================================
Printing stats:
    test_mem_1: gc collected
======================================================================
Top 3 lines
#1: lib\linecache.py:137: 63.8 KiB
    lines = fp.readlines()
#2: .\memleak.py:39: 1.2 KiB
    line = linecache.getline(frame.filename, frame.lineno).strip()
#3: lib\tracemalloc.py:509: 1.2 KiB
    statistics.sort(reverse=True, key=Statistic._sort_key)
56 other: 19.0 KiB

=====> Total allocated size: 85.3 KiB

======================================================================
Printing stats:
    loopity: test_mem_1 done
======================================================================
Top 3 lines
#1: lib\linecache.py:137: 63.8 KiB
    lines = fp.readlines()
#2: lib\tracemalloc.py:65: 3.7 KiB
    return (self.size, self.count, self.traceback)
#3: lib\tracemalloc.py:185: 2.8 KiB
    self._frames = tuple(reversed(frames))
70 other: 22.9 KiB

=====> Total allocated size: 93.2 KiB

Tested mem 1, continue to test mem 2
======================================================================
Printing stats:
    test_mem_2: start
======================================================================
Top 3 lines
#1: lib\linecache.py:137: 63.8 KiB
    lines = fp.readlines()
#2: lib\tracemalloc.py:65: 4.6 KiB
    return (self.size, self.count, self.traceback)
#3: lib\tracemalloc.py:532: 4.5 KiB
    traces = _get_traces()
71 other: 26.8 KiB

=====> Total allocated size: 99.7 KiB

======================================================================
Printing stats:
    test_mem_2: lists generated
======================================================================
Top 3 lines
#1: .\memleak.py:72: 3508.7 KiB
    keys = list(range(100000))
#2: lib\linecache.py:137: 63.8 KiB
    lines = fp.readlines()
#3: lib\tracemalloc.py:532: 9.2 KiB
    traces = _get_traces()
73 other: 31.6 KiB

=====> Total allocated size: 3613.3 KiB

======================================================================
Printing stats:
    test_mem_2: np data generated
======================================================================
Top 3 lines
#1: .\memleak.py:80: 911719.1 KiB
    data[k][lvl] = np.random.random(100) #1'000'000 X 8 = 800 MB
#2: .\memleak.py:78: 11370.0 KiB
    data[k] = {}
#3: .\memleak.py:72: 3508.7 KiB
    keys = list(range(100000))
71 other: 96.4 KiB

=====> Total allocated size: 926694.2 KiB

Data generated, awaiting input to continue
======================================================================
Printing stats:
    test_mem_2: data == None
======================================================================
Top 3 lines
#1: .\memleak.py:72: 3508.7 KiB
    keys = list(range(100000))
#2: lib\linecache.py:137: 63.8 KiB
    lines = fp.readlines()
#3: .\memleak.py:80: 5.7 KiB
    data[k][lvl] = np.random.random(100) #1'000'000 X 8 = 800 MB
75 other: 37.6 KiB

=====> Total allocated size: 3615.8 KiB

======================================================================
Printing stats:
    test_mem_2: gc collected
======================================================================
Top 3 lines
#1: .\memleak.py:72: 3508.7 KiB
    keys = list(range(100000))
#2: lib\linecache.py:137: 63.8 KiB
    lines = fp.readlines()
#3: .\memleak.py:80: 5.5 KiB
    data[k][lvl] = np.random.random(100) #1'000'000 X 8 = 800 MB
60 other: 22.0 KiB

=====> Total allocated size: 3600.0 KiB

======================================================================
Printing stats:
    loopity: test_mem_2 done
======================================================================
Top 3 lines
#1: lib\linecache.py:137: 63.8 KiB
    lines = fp.readlines()
#2: .\memleak.py:80: 5.5 KiB
    data[k][lvl] = np.random.random(100) #1'000'000 X 8 = 800 MB
#3: lib\tracemalloc.py:65: 3.9 KiB
    return (self.size, self.count, self.traceback)
73 other: 26.4 KiB

=====> Total allocated size: 99.7 KiB

Finished
```