# Use the parent's attribute but do not inherit it on child using python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Are there some way to use the class attribute from parent inside child but do not inherit it?

```
class CycleFactory:
    all_cycles = [202015, 202016, 202017, 202101]


class Cycle(int, CycleFactory):
    def __init__(self, cycle):
        self.cycle = cycle

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.all_cycles[self.all_cycles.index(self.cycle) + other]

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.all_cycles[self.all_cycles.index(self.cycle) - other]
```

This is the example code. The point is that I'll create many instances of `Cycle` class and it's running out of memory because the `all_cycles` attribute has much more items than the example, but it's fixed to all instances of `Cycle`.

How could I achieve this? Use just one fixed attribute on a parent class to do not recreate it every time when I use the child class?

I thought about using the Factory and Abstract factory patterns, but they are not related to attributes, only creating new objects using a class Factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are wrong.

```py
cycle1 = Cycle(CycleFactory.all_cycles[0])
cycle2 = Cycle(CycleFactory.all_cycles[1])
print(cycle1.cycle)  # 202015
print(cycle2.cycle)  # 202016
print(id(cycle1.all_cycles))  # 2442385684104
print(id(cycle2.all_cycles))  # 2442385684104
```

What this shows is that the two `Cycle` instances **share the same reference**. It is because `CycleFactory.all_cycles` is not an **instance variable** but a **class variable**, shared among all instances of this class and its subclasses. Proof is that :

```py
cycle1.all_cycles.append(-159)
print(cycle1.all_cycles)  # [202015, 202016, 202017, 202101, -159]
print(cycle2.all_cycles)  # [202015, 202016, 202017, 202101, -159]
```

I modified only for `cycle1` but `cycle2` also sees the modification. It is because they don't have each a copy, but each a reference. You may be interested to read the [Python's Data Model first chapter](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) about references and (im)mutability. In C parlance, we would call the distinction "value versus pointer".

So your assumption that each `Cycle` has its own copy, thus blowing up the memory usage, is incorrect. Each only have a reference (*pointer*), which is of negligible size, except if you intend to have millions of `Cycle` instances.

You should measure to be sure what is causing problems, cf [How do I profile memory usage in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/552744/11384184).

For performance problems (memory consumption here), the answer rarely comes from design patterns.
If your `all_cycles` array is very very large, I recommend you to not use lists. You seem to never modify it, so you could use a `tuple` instead, thus the change would just be :

```py
    all_cycles = (202015, 202016, 202017, 202101)
# parentheses    ^                              ^
```

But if it is not enough or if you should be able to modify it, consider using something other than **native lists**. For example, **numpy arrays** are much more memory-efficient, see [What are the advantages of NumPy over regular Python lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/993984/11384184)