# Comparison of BFS and DFS algorithm for the Knapsack problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I am fairly new to python and I have a task which tells me to compare both algorithm time expended and space used in memory.

I have coded both algorithms and ran them both. I was able to measure the time used, but wasnt able to look for ways to know how much space was used. I am also not sure if the question is asking me to calculate it based on general BFS and DFS or the code I have coded.

> Comparison of the time expended by the algorithms.
>
> Comparison of the space used in memory at a time by the algorithms

To get the time I used `start_time = time.time()` and `end = time.time()`

```
BFS algorithm
0.0060007572174072266s 
DFS algorithm
0.005002260208129883s
```

How would I calculate the space used in memory assuming that it is based on my code. I might be just confused but the wording of the question makes me feel like I need to measure it when running both algorithms to compare the performance.

---

**Code**:

*BFS* :

```
def knapsack_bfs(items, max_weight):
    queue = deque()
    root = Node(-1, 0, 0, [])
    queue.append(root)

    max_benefit = 0
    best_combination = []

    while queue:
        current = queue.popleft()

        if current.level == len(items) - 1:
            if current.benefit > max_benefit:
                max_benefit = current.benefit
                best_combination = current.items
        else:
            next_level = current.level + 1
            next_item = items[next_level]

            include_benefit = current.benefit + next_item.benefit
            include_weight = current.weight + next_item.weight

            if include_weight <= max_weight:
                include_node = Node(next_level, include_benefit,
                                    include_weight, current.items + [next_item.id])
                if include_benefit > max_benefit:
                    max_benefit = include_benefit
                    best_combination = include_node.items
                queue.append(include_node)

            exclude_node = Node(next_level, current.benefit,
                                current.weight, current.items)
            queue.append(exclude_node)

    return max_benefit, best_combination
```

*DFS*:

```
def knapsack_dfs(items, max_weight):
    queue = []
    root = Node(-1, 0, 0, [])
    queue.append(root)

    max_benefit = 0
    best_combination = []

    while queue:
        current = queue.pop()

        if current.level == len(items) - 1:
            if current.benefit > max_benefit:
                max_benefit = current.benefit
                best_combination = current.items
        else:
            next_level = current.level + 1
            next_item = items[next_level]

            include_benefit = current.benefit + next_item.benefit
            include_weight = current.weight + next_item.weight

            if include_weight <= max_weight:
                include_node = Node(next_level, include_benefit,
                                    include_weight, current.items + [next_item.id])
                if include_benefit > max_benefit:
                    max_benefit = include_benefit
                    best_combination = include_node.items
                queue.append(include_node)

            exclude_node = Node(next_level, current.benefit,
                                current.weight, current.items)
            
            queue.append(exclude_node)

    return max_benefit, best_combination
```

Edit:

Results based on the answer below:

```
program.py:42: size=4432 B (+840 B), count=79 (+15), average=56 B
program.py:116: size=0 B (-768 B), count=0 (-1)
program.py:79: size=0 B (-744 B), count=0 (-13)
program.py.py:85: size=0 B (-72 B), count=0 (-1)
program.py:57: size=0 B (-56 B), count=0 (-1)
program.py:56: size=0 B (-56 B), count=0 (-1)
program.py:74: size=0 B (-32 B), count=0 (-1)
program.py:37: size=32 B (+0 B), count=1 (+0), average=32 B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing what another answer suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45679009/670693

While I couldn't run your code to try things out, missing the `Node` definition, you can try something like:

```py
import tracemalloc

tracemalloc.start()
knapsack_dfs(...)
dfs_snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
knapsack_bfs(...)
bfs_snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
tracemalloc.stop()

bfs_snapshot = bfs_snapshot.filter_traces((tracemalloc.Filter(False, '*tracemalloc.py'),))
dfs_snapshot = dfs_snapshot.filter_traces((tracemalloc.Filter(False, '*tracemalloc.py'),))

for statdiff in bfs_snapshot.compare_to(dfs_snapshot, 'lineno'):
  print(statdiff)
```

Comment: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/oveqeqepeh.py this is the full code

Comment: What do this result mean if you could translate them for me

Comment: It should be a line-by-line comparison of memory usage with the `size=` being from `bfs_snapshot`, and the `(+xyz B)` being the relative difference from `dfs_snapshot`.

To be frank, the data makes little sense to me since it's indicating that both `dfs` and `bfs` were using `bfs` code.