# Total memory used by Python process?

Tags: python, memory-management

Is there a way for a Python program to determine how much memory it's currently using? I've seen discussions about memory usage for a single object, but what I need is total memory usage for the process, so that I can determine when it's necessary to start discarding cached data.

Answer (score 549, accepted):

[Here](http://fa.bianp.net/blog/2013/different-ways-to-get-memory-consumption-or-lessons-learned-from-memory_profiler/) is a useful solution that works for various operating systems, including Linux, Windows, etc.:

```
import psutil
process = psutil.Process()
print(process.memory_info().rss)  # in bytes
```

Notes:

- do `pip install psutil` if it is not installed yet
- handy one-liner if you quickly want to know how many MiB your process takes:

  ```
  import os, psutil; print(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2)
  ```
- with Python 2.7 and psutil 5.6.3, it was `process.memory_info()[0]` instead (there was a change in the API later).

Comment: `psutil` is cross platform and can return the same values as the `ps` command line tool: http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.memory_info

Comment: "(`psutil`) currently supports Linux, Windows, OSX, FreeBSD and Sun Solaris, both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures, with Python versions from 2.6 to 3.4"  from [Documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil#downloads)

Comment: Why doesn't this number match the one in the process explorer?  The number from psutil always seems to be larger by about 10%.

Comment: Note that psutil is not in the standard library

Comment: @wordsforthewise my guess is that the process monitoring program (I'm on OS X, but likely the same on Linux and Windows) is sampling the memory usage over time and missing the absolute peak

Comment: If using Ubuntu, you can install `psutil` with `apt`: `sudo apt install python3-psutil`

Comment: For recent versions of `psutil`, `psutil.Process()` is equivalent to `psutil.Process(os.getpid())`.  That's one less thing you need to remember to type.

Comment: Why do you use rss? In psutil document: rss    | resident set size, vms    | total program size. So I think last line should be `print(process.memory_info().vms)`

Comment: Totally agree to @HalilİbrahimOymacı: RSS is physical memory. That's the wrong metric in >90% of the cases. A lot of effects cannot be observed. And: A high RSS is good, because you actually make use of RAM. That's better than use of hard disk, because it's faster.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21049737/6037395) explains difference between `resident set size` and `virtual memory size` very well.

Comment: To print memory usage in human readable form using the `humanize` package: `humanize.naturalsize(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss)`. Example `2.9 GB`

Answer (score 292):

For Unix based systems (Linux, Mac OS X, Solaris), you can use the `getrusage()` function from the standard library module [`resource`](https://docs.python.org/library/resource.html). The resulting object has the attribute `ru_maxrss`, which gives the *peak* memory usage for the calling process:

```
>>> resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
2656  # peak memory usage (kilobytes on Linux, bytes on OS X)
```

The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/library/resource.html#resource-usage) don't make note of the units. Refer to your specific system's [`man getrusage.2`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) page to check the unit for the value. On Ubuntu 18.04, the unit is noted as kilobytes. On Mac OS X, it's bytes.

The `getrusage()` function can also be given `resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN` to get the usage for child processes, and (on some systems) `resource.RUSAGE_BOTH` for total (self and child) process usage.

If you care only about Linux, you can alternatively read the `/proc/self/status` or `/proc/self/statm` file as described in other answers for this question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897941/) one too.

Comment: Okay, will do. I wasn't sure if SO had a process for merging questions or what.

The duplicate post was partly to show people there was a standard library solution on both questions... and partly for the rep. ;)

Should I delete this answer?

Comment: Oh, it appears I can't flag duplicates with my current rep - the "flag" link under questions doesn't even appear for me.

Comment: Now you've got more than enough rep to flag :)

Comment: Note: On linux ``ru_maxrss`` returns a value indicating the number of memory pages used.  ``ru_idrss`` returns private memory use in kilobytes.

Comment: tried to use `ru_maxrss` and `ru_idrss`, in both cases got incorrect results for heavy processes. When memory consumption of my process exceeds 4GB, the counter resets to zero. I expect that this is related to 64-bit architecture, will try other solutions. OS X 10.8 64bit.

Comment: The `ru_maxrss` reports the wrong number (doesn't correspond to `ps aux <PID>` before and after wasting some memory) on Mac OS, and all of the other `.ru_*rss` properties return None.

Comment: Mac OS definitely returns the RSS in bytes, Linux returns it in kilobytes.

Comment: The units are NOT in kilobytes. It is platform dependent, so you have to use resource.getpagesize() to find out. The given Python docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html#resource-usage) is actually very clear about it. It is 4096 in my box.

Comment: (And on OSX, even if resource.getpagesize() reports 4096, the units of ru_maxrss are still single bytes.)

Comment: @BenLin Those Python docs are clearly wrong, or there is a bug on the Mac version. The unit used by getrusage and the value returned by getpagesize are definitely different.

Comment: The question asked for **current** usage. Note that this is **maximum** usage. (Still a useful answer, just warning people who mistakenly copy-paste it.)

Comment: That's weird, both the Linux man pages <https://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage> and the Mac (well, iPhoneOS) man pages <https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/getrusage.2.html> say `ru_maxrss` is in kilobytes. No mention of bytes or pages.

Comment: According to https://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage a lot of the fields are not set in linux. (eg. the fields related to the current memory usage).

Answer (score 69):

On Windows, you can use WMI ([home page](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi.html), [cheeseshop](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/1.3.2)):

```py
def memory():
    import os
    from wmi import WMI
    w = WMI('.')
    result = w.query("SELECT WorkingSet FROM Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process WHERE IDProcess=%d" % os.getpid())
    return int(result[0].WorkingSet)
```

On Linux (from python cookbook http://code.activestate.com/recipes/286222/:

```
import os
_proc_status = '/proc/%d/status' % os.getpid()

_scale = {'kB': 1024.0, 'mB': 1024.0*1024.0, 'KB': 1024.0, 'MB': 1024.0*1024.0}

def _VmB(VmKey):
    '''Private.'''
    global _proc_status, _scale
     # get pseudo file  /proc/<pid>/status
    try:
        t = open(_proc_status)
        v = t.read()
        t.close()
    except:
        return 0.0  # non-Linux?
     # get VmKey line e.g. 'VmRSS:  9999  kB\n ...'
    i = v.index(VmKey)
    v = v[i:].split(None, 3)  # whitespace
    if len(v) < 3:
        return 0.0  # invalid format?
     # convert Vm value to bytes
    return float(v[1]) * _scale[v[2]]

def memory(since=0.0):
    '''Return memory usage in bytes.'''
    return _VmB('VmSize:') - since

def resident(since=0.0):
    '''Return resident memory usage in bytes.'''
    return _VmB('VmRSS:') - since

def stacksize(since=0.0):
    '''Return stack size in bytes.'''
    return _VmB('VmStk:') - since
```

Comment: The Windows code doesn't work for me.  This change does: `return int(result[0].WorkingSet)`

Comment: This Windows code doesn't work for me on Windows 7 x64, even after John Fouhy's comment modification.

Comment: I have this error: 
 return [ _wmi_object (obj, instance_of, fields) for obj in self._raw_query(wql) ]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\util.py", line 84, in next
    return _get_good_object_(self._iter_.next(), resultCLSID = self.resultCLSID)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147217385, 'OLE error 0x80041017', None, None)

if anyone can help me?

I have win 8 x64 but python on x32

Comment: Note: I updated the windows example following John Fouhy's suggestion after inspecting the (latest) source of the wmi module.  See also [(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786049/how-to-get-the-memory-working-set-of-a-64bit-process-in-python-2-7-32bit), [(2)](http://bugs.python.org/file19215/memory.py).

Comment: @jedwards: WorkingSet is a very bad number in >90% of the cases. It's just that part of memory which is currently in RAM

Comment: Does the Window's code return amount of RAM in use in bytes/kilobytes/etc?

Comment: Bytes. See https://wutils.com/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_perfrawdata_perfproc_process/#workingset_properties

Answer (score 45):

On unix, you can use the `ps` tool to monitor it:

```
$ ps u -p 1347 | awk '{sum=sum+$6}; END {print sum/1024}'
```

where 1347 is some process id. Also, the result is in MB.

Answer (score 27):

Current memory usage of the current process **on Linux**, for Python **2**, Python **3**, and **pypy**, without any imports:

```py
def getCurrentMemoryUsage():
    ''' Memory usage in kB '''

    with open('/proc/self/status') as f:
        memusage = f.read().split('VmRSS:')[1].split('\n')[0][:-3]

    return int(memusage.strip())
```

It reads the status file of the current process, takes everything after `VmRSS:`, then takes everything before the first newline (isolating the value of VmRSS), and finally cuts off the last 3 bytes which are a space and the unit (kB).
To return, it strips any whitespace and returns it as a number.

Tested on Linux 4.4 and 4.9, but even an early Linux version should work: looking in `man proc` and searching for the info on the `/proc/$PID/status` file, it mentions minimum versions for some fields (like Linux 2.6.10 for "VmPTE"), but the "VmRSS" field (which I use here) has no such mention. Therefore I assume it has been in there since an early version.

Answer (score 12):

Below is my function decorator which allows to track how much memory this process consumed before the function call, how much memory it uses after the function call, and how long the function is executed.

```
import time
import os
import psutil


def elapsed_since(start):
    return time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(time.time() - start))


def get_process_memory():
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    return process.memory_info().rss


def track(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        mem_before = get_process_memory()
        start = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        elapsed_time = elapsed_since(start)
        mem_after = get_process_memory()
        print("{}: memory before: {:,}, after: {:,}, consumed: {:,}; exec time: {}".format(
            func.__name__,
            mem_before, mem_after, mem_after - mem_before,
            elapsed_time))
        return result
    return wrapper
```

So, when you have some function decorated with it

```
from utils import track

@track
def list_create(n):
    print("inside list create")
    return [1] * n
```

You will be able to see this output:

```
inside list create
list_create: memory before: 45,928,448, after: 46,211,072, consumed: 282,624; exec time: 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 9):

Even easier to use than `/proc/self/status`: `/proc/self/statm`. It's just a space delimited list of several [statistics](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). I haven't been able to tell if both files are always present.

> /proc/[pid]/statm
>
> Provides information about memory usage, measured in pages.
>                 The columns are:
>
> - size       (1) total program size
>                              (same as VmSize in /proc/[pid]/status)
> - resident   (2) resident set size
>                              (same as VmRSS in /proc/[pid]/status)
> - shared     (3) number of resident shared pages (i.e., backed by a file)
>                              (same as RssFile+RssShmem in /proc/[pid]/status)
> - text       (4) text (code)
> - lib        (5) library (unused since Linux 2.6; always 0)
> - data       (6) data + stack
> - dt         (7) dirty pages (unused since Linux 2.6; always 0)

Here's a simple example:

```
from pathlib import Path
from resource import getpagesize

PAGESIZE = getpagesize()
PATH = Path('/proc/self/statm')


def get_resident_set_size() -> int:
    """Return the current resident set size in bytes."""
    # statm columns are: size resident shared text lib data dt
    statm = PATH.read_text()
    fields = statm.split()
    return int(fields[1]) * PAGESIZE


data = []
start_memory = get_resident_set_size()
for _ in range(10):
    data.append('X' * 100000)
    print(get_resident_set_size() - start_memory)
```

That produces a list that looks something like this:

```
0
0
368640
368640
368640
638976
638976
909312
909312
909312
```

You can see that it jumps by about 300,000 bytes after roughly 3 allocations of 100,000 bytes.

Comment: For those in need of higher accuracy, [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) suggests using `/proc/[pid]/smaps`, but that's a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 8):

For Python 3.6 and psutil 5.4.5 it is easier to use `memory_percent()` function listed [here](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.memory_percent).

```
import os
import psutil
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print(process.memory_percent())
```

Comment: this requires lib psutil

Answer (score 7):

I like [it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/938754/686105), thank you for @bayer. I get a specific process count tool, now.

```
# Megabyte.
$ ps aux | grep python | awk '{sum=sum+$6}; END {print sum/1024 " MB"}'
87.9492 MB

# Byte.
$ ps aux | grep python | awk '{sum=sum+$6}; END {print sum " KB"}'
90064 KB
```

Attach my process list.

```
$ ps aux  | grep python
root       943  0.0  0.1  53252  9524 ?        Ss   Aug19  52:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/beaver -c /etc/beaver/beaver.conf -l /var/log/beaver.log -P /var/run/beaver.pid
root       950  0.6  0.4 299680 34220 ?        Sl   Aug19 568:52 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/beaver -c /etc/beaver/beaver.conf -l /var/log/beaver.log -P /var/run/beaver.pid
root      3803  0.2  0.4 315692 36576 ?        S    12:43   0:54 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/beaver -c /etc/beaver/beaver.conf -l /var/log/beaver.log -P /var/run/beaver.pid
jonny    23325  0.0  0.1  47460  9076 pts/0    S+   17:40   0:00 python
jonny    24651  0.0  0.0  13076   924 pts/4    S+   18:06   0:00 grep python
```

### Reference

- [memory - Linux: find out what process is using all the RAM? - Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1037753/205255)
- [Total memory used by Python process? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/938754/686105)
- [linux - ps aux output meaning - Super User](https://superuser.com/a/117921/205255)

Comment: just an optimisation of code to avoid multi pipe `ps aux | awk '/python/{sum+=$6}; END {print sum/1024 " MB"}'`

Answer (score 5):

```
import os, win32api, win32con, win32process
han = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|win32con.PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, os.getpid())
process_memory = int(win32process.GetProcessMemoryInfo(han)['WorkingSetSize'])
```

Comment: This could be improved with some explanation of what it does and how it works.

Comment: Based on the large number returned (8 digits) and how I'm not doing much of anything, I'm guessing this has to be bytes? So it's around 28.5 MB for a rather idle interactive instance. (Wow... I didn't even realize the above comment was mine from 4 years ago... that's weird.)

Answer (score 4):

For Unix systems command `time` (/usr/bin/time) gives you that info if you pass -v. See `Maximum resident set size` below, which is the **maximum** (peak) **real** (not virtual) **memory that was used during program execution**:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -v ls /

    Command being timed: "ls /"
    User time (seconds): 0.00
    System time (seconds): 0.01
    Percent of CPU this job got: 250%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.00
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 315
    Voluntary context switches: 2
    Involuntary context switches: 0
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```

Comment: Note that this may fail if you just try to use `time` instead of `/usr/bin/time`. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/434289/why-doesnt-the-time-command-work-with-any-option

Answer (score 3):

Using sh and os to get into python bayer's answer.

```
float(sh.awk(sh.ps('u','-p',os.getpid()),'{sum=sum+$6}; END {print sum/1024}'))
```

Answer is in megabytes.

Comment: Should be noted that `sh' isn't a stdlib module.  It's installable with pip, though.