# Why is memory usage increasing in this python code?

Tags: python, memory-management, garbage-collection

I'm sure this is a naive question about python and garbage collection.

I have a function that creates a large data structure in memory, and then returns an integer.

I expected that after calling the function, the memory used by the data structure would be released.

However, if I understand what the resource call below is doing (thanks to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process)), that does not seem to be the case.  With every call to the function, the total memory used by python appears to increase. (I am using Python 2.7.1.)

```
import resource
import random
def r(n):
    a = [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(1,n)]
    return n  # or sum(a)

resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
z=r(100000)
resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
z=r(100000)
resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
```

To which I get, e.g.:

```
81584128
84389888
85995520
```

Why does the memory usage keep increasing?

Thanks!

Comment: Memory released != memory freed. The interpreter may reuse the memory allocated for an object to keep other objects, without first freeing it.

Comment: @Bakuriu: but in this specific case, it isn't reusing the memory in an optimal way. (When I run this, memory usage stabilizes right after the first call to `r`.)

Comment: thanks - but see my comment below

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because with each call to the function you are creating a list a. I would have thought that as soon as the function exits the list is dumped and the used space is freed but maybe that's not the case or doesn't happen that fast.

Comment: cf Bakuriu's comment - the list is indeed garbage collected when exiting the function but a/ the interpreter may want to keep that memory for future reuse (since memory allocation has a cost) and b/ even deallocating that memory doesn't mean the system will reclaim it immediatly.

Comment: thanks. But here's my problem: I am running this function on a web server, and running out of memory on the server, i.e. when I do
    ps -o pid,pcpu,rss,command
it shows the amount of memory I am using (rss) going up and up, and eventually the server complains.  Is there a way I can stop this behavior? Or have I misdiagnosed the problem?

Comment: You could use a generator instead of a list which should solve the problem right away if the memory is really being filled with lists.

Comment: I like the idea, but I'm not sure I can do that for my real problem: I tried to abstract the problem to its core in my question above.  In reality my function builds a large tree via dynamic programming with memoization (like in the classic Fibonacci example, e.g. http://technotroph.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/memoize-it-the-python-way/). I only keep the answer at the end, not the tree.