# Debugging reference counting memory leaks in Python C extension modules

Tags: python, c, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I'm trying to determine if there are any reference counting memory leaks in a Python C extension module. Consider this very simple test extension that leaks a `date` object:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <datetime.h>

static PyObject* memleak(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    PyDate_FromDate(2000, 1, 1); /* deliberately create a memory leak */
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

static PyMethodDef memleak_methods[] = {
    {"memleak",  memleak, METH_NOARGS, "Leak some memory"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}        /* Sentinel */
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC initmemleak(void) {
    PyDateTime_IMPORT;
    Py_InitModule("memleak", memleak_methods);
}
```

PyDate_FromDate creates a new reference (i.e. internally calls Py_INCREF) and since I never call Py_DECREF, this object will never get garbage collected.

However, when I call this function, the number of objects being tracked by the garbage collector doesn't seem to change before and after the function call:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 05:13:16)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from memleak import memleak
>>> import gc
>>> gc.disable()
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>> len(gc.get_objects()) # get object count before
3581
>>> memleak()
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>> len(gc.get_objects()) # get object count after
3581
```

And I can't seem to find the leaked `date` object at all in the list of objects returned by `gc.get_objects()`:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> print [obj for obj in gc.get_objects() if isinstance(obj, date)]
[]
```

Am I missing something here about how `gc.get_objects()` works? Is there another way to demonstrate that the memleak() function has a memory leak?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation of the [`gc`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/gc.html) module:

> Since the collector **supplements** the reference counting already used
>   in Python, you can disable the collector if you are sure your program
>   does not create **reference cycles**.

So the `gc` module is used **only** to deal with references cycles. In your case there is no cycle, hence the `date` object isn't returned by the `get_objects` function.

In fact old versions of python did not have the garbage collector at all, they only used reference-counting. The garbage collector was introduced to avoid creating memory leaks with reference-cycles(since this can be done from the python side pretty easily, and you do not want that a pure-python programs create memory leaks).

To see that kind of memory leak you should call the `memleak` function in a loop and see that the memory used increases (slowly in your case).

There are also some 3rd party libraries that can be used to profile memory usage, see the [Which Python memory profiler is recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/which-python-memory-profiler-is-recommended) question on SO.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now. I ended up [using the resource module](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7669482/2113516) to measure the growth in memory usage in order to test specific functions for memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

For this type of debugging, you want to use an instance of Python that is compiled with the `--with-pydebug` option. One of the features enabled by debug mode is tracking the total number of reference counts via a new function in the `sys` module - `gettotalrefcount()`.

For more information, see http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html#debugging-builds

Answer (score -5):

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <datetime.h>

static PyObject* memleak(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    PyObject* date=PyDate_FromDate(2000, 1, 1); /* deliberately create a memory leak */
    Py_DECREF(date);
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

static PyMethodDef memleak_methods[] = {
    {"memleak",  memleak, METH_NOARGS, "Leak some memory"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}        /* Sentinel */
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC initmemleak(void) {
    PyDateTime_IMPORT;
    Py_InitModule("memleak", memleak_methods);
}
```

Solve your problem Py_DECREF(date);

Comment: The memory leak is intentional. The question is about how to detect memory leaks.