# python memory intensive script

Tags: python, numpy

After about 4 weeks of learning, experimenting, etc. I finally have a script which does what I want. It changes the perspective of images according to a certain projection matrix I have created. When I run the script for one image it works fine, however I would like to plot six images in one figure. When I try to do this I get a memory error.

All the images are 2448px in width and 2048 px in height each. My script:

```
files = {'cam1': 'c1.jpg',
         'cam2': 'c2.jpg',
         'cam3': 'c3.jpg',
         'cam4': 'c4.jpg',
         'cam5': 'c5.jpg',
         'cam6': 'c6.jpg'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for camname in files:
    img = Image.open(files[camname])
    gray_img = np.asarray(img.convert("L"))
    img = np.asarray(img)
    height, width, channels = img.shape

    usedP = np.array(P[camname][:,[0,1,3]])
    usedPinv = np.linalg.inv(usedP)
    U, V = np.meshgrid(range(gray_img.shape[1]),
                       range(gray_img.shape[0]))
    UV = np.vstack((U.flatten(),
                    V.flatten())).T
    ones = np.ones((UV.shape[0],1))
    UV = np.hstack((UV, ones))

    # create UV_warped
    UV_warped = usedPinv.dot(UV.T).T

    # normalize vector by dividing by the third column (which should be 1)
    normalize_vector = UV_warped[:,2].T
    UV_warped = UV_warped/normalize_vector[:,None]

    # masks
    # pixels that are above the horizon and where the V-projection is therefor positive (X in argus): make 0, 0, 1
    # pixels that are to far: make 0,0,1
    masks = [UV_warped[:,0]<=0, UV_warped[:,0]>2000, UV_warped[:,1]>5000, UV_warped[:,1]<-5000] # above horizon: => [0,0,1]
    total_mask = masks[0] | masks[1] | masks[2] | masks[3]
    UV_warped[total_mask] = np.array([[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])

    # show plot
    X_warped = UV_warped[:,0].reshape((height, width))
    Y_warped = UV_warped[:,1].reshape((height, width))
    gray_img = gray_img[:-1, :-1]

    # add colors
    rgb = img[:,:-1,:].reshape((-1,3)) / 255.0 # we have 1 less faces than grid cells
    rgba = np.concatenate((rgb, np.ones((rgb.shape[0],1))), axis=1)

    plotimg = ax.pcolormesh(X_warped, Y_warped, img.mean(-1)[:,:], cmap='Greys')
    plotimg.set_array(None)
    plotimg.set_edgecolor('none')
    plotimg.set_facecolor(rgba)

ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

I have the feeling that numpy.meshgrid is quite memory intensive, but I'm not sure. Does anybody see where my memory gets eaten away rapidly? (BTW, I have a laptop with 12Gb of RAM, which is only used by other programs for a very small part)

Comment: Python as a whole, especially in memory-intensive applications, is much slower than compiled languages like C/C++. Interpreted languages like Python aren't as efficient in memory management.

Comment: You are right. However, changing to C/C++ is not an option at this point in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to profile your code with [this library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler).

It will show you where your script is using memory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm however not really a hero when it comes to using the command prompt... I tried it but I haven't got it working yet

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think I found the problem. The script loads the images using float64 types which seem to use a lot of memory.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/110259/2809083) about memory profilers. Also, I've used the trick in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7669482/2809083) in the past as a quick way to get an idea where in the code memory is going out of control. I just print the resource.getrusage() results all over the place. It's not clean, and it doesn't always work, but it's part of the standard library and it's easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

I ordinarily profile with the `profile` and `cProfile` modules, as it makes testing individual sections of code fairly easy.

[Python Profilers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile)