# Pandas GroupBy memory deallocation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, memory-management

#### Problem

I noticed that memory allocated while iterating through a Pandas [GroupBy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) object is not deallocated after iteration. I use `resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss` ([second answer in this post for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process)) to measure the total amount of active memory used by the Python process.

```
import resource
import gc

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

i = np.random.choice(list(range(100)), 4000)
cols = list(range(int(2e4)))

df = pd.DataFrame(1, index=i, columns=cols)

gb = df.groupby(level=0)
# gb = list(gb)
for i in range(3):
    print(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss / 1e6)
    for idx, x in enumerate(gb):
        if idx == 0:
            print(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss / 1e6)
    # del idx, x
    # gc.collect()
```

prints the following total active memory (in gb)

```
0.671732
1.297424
1.297952
1.923288
1.923288
2.548624
```

#### Solutions

Uncommenting `del idx, x` and `gc.collect()` fixes the problem. I do however have to `del` all variables that reference the DataFrames returned by iterating over the groupby (which can be a pain depending on the code in the inner for loop). The new printed memory usages become:

```
0.671768
1.297412
1.297992
1.297992
1.297992
1.297992
```

Alternatively I can uncomment `gb = list(gb)`. The resulting memory usages are roughly the same as those from the previous solution:

```
1.32874
1.32874
1.32874
1.32874
1.32874
1.32874
```

#### Questions

1. Why is memory for DataFrames resulting from iteration through the groupby not deallocated after iteration is completed?
2. Is there a better solution than the two above? If not, which of these two solutions is "better"?

Comment: Are you using python2 or 3?

Comment: It is strange, there are new objects created on each iteration and somehow there is a reference being kept so just calling gc.collect is not enough. Using the list approach the same objects are reused so you see no increase in memeory.

Answer (score 1):

## Memory Weirdness

This is *very* interesting!  You do not need `del idx, x`. Only using `gc.collect()` worked to keep memory constant for me.  This is much cleaner that having the `del` statements inside the loop.

Comment: I do not get the same results. If I don't `del` the reference `x` then memory increases twice (~0.67gb -> ~1.3gb -> 2gb).

Comment: Hmm... I ran this in iPython and `del` was not needed... what are you running this in?

Comment: You mean what version of Pandas? 0.18.0

Comment: What environment? Inside iPython? Command line? Part of another full application?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is memory for DataFrames resulting from iteration through the groupby not deallocated after iteration is completed?

Nowhere in your code you `del` object `gb`, which means at the end it's still there. One thing is to have an iterator reach the end of its cycle, then I would expect it to die automagically, but the object that gave rise to the iterator persists, in case you need to do something else (iterate again, aggregate, etc).

Comment: o.o wutizusaying