# How to get the memory usage of a Python program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am having excessive memory usage in my program. In order to debug where exactly memory usage is increasing I am using the below snippet to check the RAM Usage.

```
memory_usage = sum(sys.getsizeof(i) for i in gc.get_objects())
print('Memory usage in MB', float(usage)/1000000)
```

Is this the right way to find how much MB of memory is getting used by the Python program? If not can you suggest best way to monitor the memory usage?
I also tried

```
1. resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
2. from guppy import hpy
   h = hpy()
   print "heapsize: ", h.heap()
3.import psutil
  print "Mem usage:",psutil.virtual_memory()
```

but all of them give very very different results thereby increasing the confusion.

Comment: duplicate question of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Total memory used by Python process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process)

Comment: I included the solution recommended but that doesn't help