# Memory usage of a function in Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity, ram, space-complexity, memory-consumption

Are there any specific Python libraries to quantify practically both *space* (memory consumption) and *time complexity* (time consumption) of a specific function in Python 3.x, by providing avg/max/min stats?

Comment: By "space complexity" do you mean "maximum size in RAM over the course of the program"? Do you want the size of one particular data structure or of the entire program?

Comment: Yes, should I update the question mentioning this? I mean real experimental space complexity, not theoretical

Comment: Yes, you should edit your question to make those things that I ask clear. I did not ask about "real" versus "theoretical" since that was already clear in your question. I note that you have not yet answered either of my questions.

Comment: Ok sorry, yes I want the amount of used memory in RAM by a function. I update, thank you

Comment: Compile a bit of boilerplate code. Compile the same code with the function you want to measure. Compute the difference in memory used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the memory usage of a process using the `os` and `psutil` libraries according to the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process).