# how easy is to cause an outOfMemoryExeption in python?

Tags: python, memory, out-of-memory

Im dong a spelling bee program in python using pygame, and it works fine, but i have been testing it with 7 words, not more.
Im worried that, if used with 300 words it might cause the memory to fill.
remember there are 2 arrays: One holds the default list of words, and the other holds the randomized words.

Comment: It would likely depend on the computer it's being run on. 300 strings alone isn't going to cause memory problems though unless you're running it on a potato.

Comment: It's *easy* to use all available memory:`a = 'a'*100000000000000000`. But 300 words is not going to cause a problem on any modern system.

Comment: 300 words will not use up all your memory, no.

Comment: 1): Remember they are 600 due to being the normal list and the randomized list.

Comment: 2) Lets say its an 8Gb RAM

Comment: See [Memory error allocating list of 11,464,882 empty dicts](//stackoverflow.com/a/19456746) for an example of an actual memory issue. Note the numbers involved.

Comment: @GabrielMation dude, a million words isn't going to cause a problem. 600 words is nothing.

Comment: ok thanks. i was worried

Comment: Well, you can always just *try* it an monitor your memory usage.

Comment: @GabrielMation: lets say your words have a median 5 letters, and only use ASCII characters. Then you need 54 bytes per word (49 bytes for an empty string object, plus 5 for the ASCII letters), times 600, makes about 30Kb. That's *really very, very little memory*.

Comment: ok ok i understood

Comment: @GabrielMation In Java, I can hold 300,000+ (three hundred thousand!) English words in memory at once on my low end computer. Hundreds of words is nothing.

Comment: And you were potentially downvoted because this is fairly easy to test on your own. You could generate random words and count how many you can fit in a list before it crashes. Trying stuff yourself is the best way to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good way to find out is to try it.

You can put a line midway through your program to [print out how much memory it is using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process):

```
import os
import psutil
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print(process.memory_info().rss)
```

Try running your program with different numbers of words and plotting the results:

[image: graph plotting total memory vs. number of words]

Then you can predict how many words it would take to use up all your memory.

A few other points to keep in mind:

- If you are using 32 bit Python, your total memory will be limited by the 32 bit address space to about 4 GB.
- Your computer likely uses the disk to increase the virtual memory beyond the RAM size. So, even if you only have 1 GB RAM, you might find you can use 3 GB of memory in your program.
- For small lists of words like you are using, you will almost *never* run out of memory unless your program has a bug. In my experience, OutOfMemory is almost always because I made a mistake.

Comment: OS memory allocation is not a good way to measure this, as that happens in chunks and Python uses a heap model (meaning it'll request larger blocks).

Comment: Instead, use [`tracemalloc` snapshots](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html).

Comment: so how can i measure it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's a good point. Of course, if you are nearing using your whole RAM, os memory usage will be a decent approximation.

Comment: See [Python: Cannot replicate a test on memory usage](//stackoverflow.com/a/51031010) for a concrete discussion of a blogpost that attempted to measure Python memory use (incorrectly), the [linked gist](https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/1d9ce2c84b858ef7cb7192311e49bb49#file-test-pickle-tracemalloc-py) includes how you could use `tracemalloc` to measure memory use.

Comment: i runned the code above to see what could i get, and i have a question: The number displayed represents bytes?

Answer (score 4):

You really do not need to worry. Python is not such a memory hog as to cause issues with a mere 600 words.

With a bit of care, you can measure memory requirements directly. The [`sys.getsizeof()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) lets you measure the direct memory requirements of a given Python object (only direct memory, not anything that it references!). You could use this to measure individual strings:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof("Hello!")
55
>>> sys.getsizeof("memoryfootprint")
64
```

Exact sizes depend on the Python version and your OS. A Python string object needs a base amount of memory for a lot of book-keeping information, and then 1, 2 or 4 bytes per character, depending on the highest Unicode code point. For ASCII, that's just one byte per letter. Python 3.7, on my Mac OS X system uses 49 bytes for the bookkeeping portion.

Getting the size of a Python `list` object means you get *just the list object memory requirements*, not anything that's stored 'in' the list. You can repeatedly add the same object to a list and you'd not get copies, because [Python uses references for everything](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), including list contents. Take that into account.

So lets load 300 random words, and create two lists, to see what the memory needs will be:

```
>>> import random
>>> words = list(map(str.strip, open('/usr/share/dict/words')))  # big file of words, present on many computers
>>> words = random.sample(words, 300)  # just use 300
>>> words[:10]
['fourer', 'tampon', 'Minyadidae', 'digallic', 'euploid', 'Mograbi', 'sketchbook', 'annul', 'ambilogy', 'outtalent']
>>> import statistics
>>> statistics.mean(map(len, words))
9.346666666666666
>>> statistics.median(map(len, words))
9.0
>>> statistics.mode(map(len, words))
10
>>> sys.getsizeof(words)
2464
>>> sum(sys.getsizeof(word) for word in words)
17504
```

That's one list, with 300 unique words with an average length of just over 9 characters, and that required 2464 bytes for the list, and 17504 bytes for the words themselves. That's less that not even 20KB.

But, you say, you have 2 lists. But that second list will not have copies of your words, that's just more references to the existing words, so that'll only take another 2464 bytes, so 2KB.

*For 300 random English words, in two lists, your total memory requirements are around 20KB of memory*.

On an 8GB machine, you will not have any problems. Note that I loaded the *whole* `words` file in one go into my computer, and then cut that back to 300 random words. Here is how much memory that whole initial list requires:

```
>>> words = list(map(str.strip, open('/usr/share/dict/words')))
>>> len(words)
235886
>>> sum(sys.getsizeof(word) for word in words)
13815637
>>> sys.getsizeof(words)
2007112
```

That's about 15MB of memory, for close to 236 thousand words.

If you are worried about larger programs with more objects, that you can also use the [`tracemalloc` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html) to get statistics about memory use:

```
last = None
def display_memory_change(msg):
    global last
    snap = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
    statdiff, last = snap.compare_to(last, 'filename', True), snap
    tot = sum(s.size for s in statdiff)
    change = sum(s.size_diff for s in statdiff)
    print('{:>20} (Tot: {:6.1f} MiB, Inc: {:6.1f} MiB)'.format(
        msg, tot / 2 ** 20, change / 2 ** 20))


# at the start, get a baseline
tracemalloc.start()
last = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()

# create objects, run more code, etc.

display_memory_change("Some message as to what has been done")

# run some more code.

display_memory_change("Show some more statistics")
```

Using the above code to measure reading all those words:

```
tracemalloc.start()
last = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
display_memory_change("Baseline")

words = list(map(str.strip, open('/usr/share/dict/words')))

display_memory_change("Loaded words list")
```

gives an output of

```
            Baseline (Tot:    0.0 MiB, Inc:    0.0 MiB)
   Loaded words list (Tot:   15.1 MiB, Inc:   15.1 MiB)
```

confirming my `sys.getsizeof()` measurements.

Comment: Very usefull too

Comment: if i could choose both, i would

Comment: Sorry, you can only mark one as the accepted answer. The choice is entirely yours, and not picking one is also an option.