# How much space does my python program use?

Tags: python

This must be a duplicate but i couldn't find it...

I know there's a nifty way to tell how much time my program took:

```
import time

t0 = time.time()

program

print(time.time()-t0)
```

Is there a similar simple thing i can do to see how much space was used?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21632554/7347631

Comment: Outside of your program, you'd use a Profiler to find both time and memory used.

Comment: @AndrewNaguib yes, looks like it. don't know why that didn't show up. thank you. i'll delete