# How much memory has been assigned when spawning a new process in Python

Tags: python, linux, windows, multiprocessing

I'm setting up a new Python project taking advantage of multiprocessing and want to know the default assigned memory when creating a new process in Python. I searched on the internet but it only provided the [memory used by Python process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process)

Comment: How are you creating the new process? On Linux, there can be a big difference in memory usage between a process created with `fork`+`exec` (like the Python `subprocess` module does) versus a lightweight forked copy created with `vfork` (which the `mutliprocessing` module can do, although it can be configured otherwise).

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here?  (And why is this tagged `[multithreading]`?)

Comment: @NPE The problem here is that when Python spawning a new process but I don't know about the resources the system actually reserved for that new process. When I know that, then I can have better resource management for my Python program. (For the tag `multithreading`, I'll remove it)