# Gensim find vectors/words in ball of radius r

Tags: python, gensim, word-embedding

I would like take word "book" (for example) get its vector representation, call it v_1 and find all words whose vector representation is within ball of radius r of v_1 i.e. ||v_1 - v_i||<=r, for some real number r.

I know gensim has `most_similar` function, which allows to state number of top vectors to return, but it is not quite what I need. I surely can use brute force search and get the answer, but it will be to slow.

Comment: calculate euclidean distance to the point, then filter out records farther than r

Comment: @Marat, thank you, this looks like brute force to me. I will need to loop through all words in model (yet need to find out how to do it). Anything faster?

Comment: It isn't that bad. Typically vocab size is not that big and with properly vectorized operations that will take a fraction of a second. There are some optimizations for multiple searches (like R-trees), but for a single search that's your only option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `most_similar()` with a `topn=0`, it will return the raw *unsorted* cosine-similarities to *all* other words known to the model. (These similarities will not be in tuples with the words, but simply in the same order as the words in the `index2entity` property.)

You could then filter those similarities for those higher than your preferred threshold, and return just those indexes/words, using a function like `numpy`'s [`argwhere`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21632554/130288).

For example:

```
target_word = 'apple'
threshold = 0.9
all_sims = wv.most_similar(target_word, topn=0)
satisfactory_indexes = np.argwhere(all_sims > threshold)
satisfactory_words = [wv.index2entity[i] for i in satisfactory_indexes]
```