# Python (WSGI): Get peak memory usage of each request

Tags: python, memory, thread-safety, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm using WSGI Daemon process for my Python application, I'm having a problem trying to get the memory usage of each request using the `resource` module.

It will work as I want it to if using CGI, but with WSGI, the memory usage count gets shared between requests. I believe this has something to do with threading as WSGI spawns processes & threads unlike when using CGI which just spawns a new process for each request.

Here is a minimal example of a WSGI Python application to get peak memory usage of `example.com/a` and `example.com/b`:

```
def application(environ, start_response):

    if environ['REQUEST_URI'] == '/a':
        pass

    elif environ['REQUEST_URI'] == '/b':

        # Use lots of memory
        x = ''
        for _i in range(0, 30000):
            x += ('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaqaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
                  'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
                  'aaaaaaaaaaaaawaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
                  'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
                  'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
                  'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
                  'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
                  'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
                  'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
                  'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')

    # Show peak memory used
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process#answer-7669482
    import resource
    mem = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
    content = str(mem)

    status = '200 OK'
    header = [('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')]
    start_response(status, header)
    content = content.encode('utf-8')
    return [content]
```

If I visit `example.com/a` the memory usage will show `~30008`
If I visit `example.com/b` the memory usage will show `~47984`
But if I visit `example.com/a` again (after visiting `example.com/b`), it will show `~47984` instead of `~3008`.

What I want to happen for the above code is:
`example.com/a` to always show `~30008`
`example.com/b` to always show `~47984`

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What you want is not how the memory management works. Tou shouldn't expect the memory usage of the worker processes to go down.

Comment: I didn't mean to say "expect", I'm not sure how WSGI is working, I meant to say "what I want to happen".

Comment: I know what you meant and it's not going to happen.